# Improving mesh and NDSolve solution convergence

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh, convergence

I have developed the code below to solve two PDEs; first mu[x,y] is solved for, then the results of mu are used to solve for phi[x,y]. The code works and converges on a solution as is, however, I would like to decrease the size of a, b, and d even further. To accurately represent the physical process I am trying to simulate, a, b, and d would need to be ~100-1000x smaller. If I make them smaller, I don't believe the solution has actually converged because the values for phi along the right boundary change significantly with a change in mesh size (i.e. if I make them smaller and the code below produces a value of phi=-0.764 at the midpoint between y2 and y3 along the right boundary, a change in size1 to 10^-17 and size2 to 10^-15, changes that value of phi to -0.763, and a change in size2 to 10^-16 changes that value again to -0.860), but I cannot make the mesh size any smaller without Mathematica crashing.

Are there any better ways to create the mesh that would be less computationally taxing and allow it to be more refined in the regions of interest? Or are there any ways to make the code in general less computationally expensive so that I can further refine the mesh?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
(* 1) Define Constants*)
e = 1.60217662*10^-19;
F = 96485;
kb = 1.381*10^-23;
sigi = 18;
sigini = 0;
sigeni = 2*10^6;
T = 1000;
n = -0.02;
c = 1; 
pH2 = 0.2;
pH2O = 1 - pH2;
pO2 = 1.52*^-19;
l = 10*10^-6;
a = 100*10^-7;
b = 50*10^-7;
d = 300*10^-7;
y1 = 0.01;
y2 = 0.5*y1;
y3 = y2 + a;
y4 = y3 + d;
y5 = y4 + b;
mu1 = 0;
mu2 = -5.98392*^-19;
phi1 = 0;

(* 2) Create mesh*)
m = 0.1*l;
size1 = 10^-16;
size2 = 10^-15;
size3 = 10^-7;
mrf = With[{rmf = 
     RegionMember[
      Region@RegionUnion[Disk[{l, y2}, m], Disk[{l, y3}, m], 
        Disk[{l, y4}, m], Disk[{l, y5}, m]]]}, 
   Function[{vertices, area}, Block[{x, y}, {x, y} = Mean[vertices];
     Which[rmf[{x, y}], 
      area > size1, (0 <= x <= l && y2 - l <= y <= y2 + l), 
      area > size2, (0 <= x <= l && y3 - l <= y <= y3 + l), 
      area > size2, (0 <= x <= l && y4 - l <= y <= y4 + l), 
      area > size2, (0 <= x <= l && y5 - l <= y <= y5 + l), 
      area > size2, True, area > size3]]]];
mesh = DiscretizeRegion[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {l, y1}], 
   MeshRefinementFunction -> mrf];

(* 3) Solve for mu*)
bcmu = {DirichletCondition[mu[x, y] == mu1, (x == 0 && 0 < y < y1)],
   DirichletCondition[
    mu[x, y] == 
     mu2, (x == l && y2 <=  y <=  y3) || (x == l && y4 <= y <= y5)]};
solmu = NDSolve[{Laplacian[mu[x, y], {x, y}] == 
     0 + NeumannValue[0, y == 0 || y == y1 ||
        (x == l && 0 <= y < y2) || (x == l && 
          y3 < y < y4) || (x == l && y5 < y < y1)], bcmu}, 
   mu, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, WorkingPrecision -> 50];

(* 4) Solve for electronic conductivity everywhere*)
pO2data = Exp[(mu[x, y] /. solmu)/kb/T];
sige0 = 2.77*10^-7;
sigedata = Piecewise[{{sige0*pO2data^(-1/4), 0 <= x <= l - m},
    {sige0*pO2data^(-1/4), (l - m < x <= l && 0 <= y < y2)},
    {(sigeni - sige0*(pO2data /. x -> l - m)^(-1/4))/m*(x - (l - m)) +
       sige0*(pO2data /. x -> l - m)^(-1/4), (l - m < x <= l && 
       y2 <=  y <= y3)},
    {sige0*pO2data^(-1/4), (l - m < x <= l && y3 < y < y4)},
    {(sigeni - sige0*(pO2data /. x -> l - m)^(-1/4))/m*(x - (l - m)) +
       sige0*(pO2data /. x -> l - m)^(-1/4), (l - m < x <= l && 
       y4 <= y <= y5)},
    {sige0*pO2data^(-1/4), (l - m < x <= l && y5 < y <= y1)}}];

(* 5) Solve for phi*)
Irxn = -(2*F)*(c*pO2^n );
A = (Irxn - sigi/(4*e)*(D[mu[x, y] /. solmu, x] /. x -> l))/(-sigi);
B = sigi/(4*e)*(D[mu[x, y] /. solmu, x] /. 
      x -> l)/(sigi + sigedata /. x -> l - m);
bcphi = DirichletCondition[phi[x, y] == phi1, (x == 0 && 0 < y < y1)];
solphi = NDSolve[{Laplacian[phi[x, y], {x, y}] == 
     0 + NeumannValue[0, 
       y == 0 || 
        y == y1 || (x == l && 0 <= y < y2) || (x == l && 
          y3 < y < y4) || (x == l && y5 < y < y1)] + 
      NeumannValue[-A[[1]], (x == l && y2 <= y <= y3)] + 
      NeumannValue[-B[[1]], (x == l && y4 <= y <= y5)], bcphi}, 
   phi, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, WorkingPrecision -> 50];

(* 6) Print values to check for convergence*)
P[x_, y_] := phi[x, y] /. solphi;
P[l, (y3 - y2)/2 + y2]
P[l, (y5 - y4)/2 + y4]
```

Comment: Hm. This is a really difficult problem and I am not sure whether FEM is a good approach for it. The Neumann data for `phi` has jumps. So the maximal regularity of the true solution that one may expect is $W^{3/2,p}$ for $1<p<\infty$ which means that the convergence rate in $L^p$ of Galerkin solution is about $h^{1/2}$. The convergence rate in $C^0$ (which is what you need for point evaluations) is _way_ lower, in particular at the boundary. This would require super fine meshes. But those are hard to obtain with nicely shaped triangles, because the aspect ratio of the domain is abnormally high.

Comment: I am not an expert, but maybe the boundary element method (BEM, which unfortunately is not supported by _Mathematica_) is a better strategy for this problem. It should be applicable because there is only Neumann data "on the right hand side", e.g., solution are indeed harmonic in the interior of the domain.

Comment: @kjcole, what problem do you try to solve?

Comment: Version 13 has [ToGradedMesh](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToGradedMesh.html) and [ElementMeshRegionProduct](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ElementMeshRegionProduct.html).

Answer (score 10):

The OP has asked a number of related questions involving the same FEM operators [226503](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/226503/61809), [226486](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/226486/61809), [222834](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/222947/61809).  As I showed in my answer [222834](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/222947/61809) to an earlier question from the OP, this system would benefit from dimensional analysis and that an anisotropic structured quad mesh is probably the most robust solution to the problem.

Dimensional analysis would aid in viewing the mesh of very high aspect ratio domains and identifying important dimensionless groups. Doing so can help prevent an endless game of Whack-A-Mole by reducing the number of independent variables and negative interactions of those variables.

The geometric model has high aspect ratios and many small features.  The physics has many locations where sharp gradients of the dependent variable occur requiring a very fine mesh to prevent false diffusion.  Many advanced meshers have boundary layer meshing capability (i.e., the ability to create thin high aspect ratio elements on surfaces) to capture sharp gradients.  Unfortunately, the automatic mesher of [`ToElementMesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToElementMesh.html) does not currently have boundary layer meshing capability and will try to create isotropic elements that will necessarily blow up the model size if one desires to capture the gradients accurately.  Fortunately, ToElementMesh will allow one to create their own structured mesh and rolling your own boundary layer mesh for rectangular domains can be done with some effort as I will show.

## Setup

First, import the necessary packages and define some helper functions and constants.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
(* Define Some Helper Functions For Structured Quad Mesh*)
pointsToMesh[data_] :=
  MeshRegion[Transpose[{data}], 
   Line@Table[{i, i + 1}, {i, Length[data] - 1}]];
unitMeshGrowth[n_, r_] := 
 Table[(r^(j/(-1 + n)) - 1.)/(r - 1.), {j, 0, n - 1}]
unitMeshGrowth2Sided [nhalf_, r_] := (1 + Union[-Reverse@#, #])/2 &@
  unitMeshGrowth[nhalf, r]
meshGrowth[x0_, xf_, n_, r_] := (xf - x0) unitMeshGrowth[n, r] + x0
firstElmHeight[x0_, xf_, n_, r_] := 
 Abs@First@Differences@meshGrowth[x0, xf, n, r]
lastElmHeight[x0_, xf_, n_, r_] := 
 Abs@Last@Differences@meshGrowth[x0, xf, n, r]
findGrowthRate[x0_, xf_, n_, fElm_] := 
 Quiet@Abs@
   FindRoot[firstElmHeight[x0, xf, n, r] - fElm, {r, 1.0001, 100000}, 
     Method -> "Brent"][[1, 2]]
meshGrowthByElm[x0_, xf_, n_, fElm_] := 
 N@Sort@Chop@meshGrowth[x0, xf, n, findGrowthRate[x0, xf, n, fElm]]
meshGrowthByElmSym[x0_, xf_, n_, fElm_] := 
 With[{mid = Mean[{x0, xf}]}, 
  Union[meshGrowthByElm[mid, x0, n, fElm], 
   meshGrowthByElm[mid, xf, n, fElm]]]
reflectRight[pts_] := With[{rt = ReflectionTransform[{1}, {Last@pts}]},
  Union[pts, Flatten[rt /@ Partition[pts, 1]]]]
reflectLeft[pts_] := 
 With[{rt = ReflectionTransform[{-1}, {First@pts}]},
  Union[pts, Flatten[rt /@ Partition[pts, 1]]]]
extendMesh[mesh_, newmesh_] := Union[mesh, Max@mesh + newmesh]
uniformPatch[p1_, p2_, \[Rho]_] := 
 With[{d = p2 - p1}, Subdivide[0, d, 2 + Ceiling[d \[Rho]]]]

(*1) Define Constants*)
e = 1.60217662*10^-19;
F = 96485;
kb = 1.381*10^-23;
sigi = 18;
sigini = 0;
sigeni = 2*10^6;
T = 1000;
n = -0.02;
c = 1;
pH2 = 0.2;
pH2O = 1 - pH2;
pO2 = 1.52*^-19;
l = 10*10^-6;
mu1 = 0;
mu2 = -5.98392*^-19;
phi1 = 0;
m = 0.1*l;
sige0 = 2.77*10^-7;
Irxn = -(2*F)*(c*pO2^n);
```

## Anisotropic Quad Mesh Workflow

Using scaled coordinates (that we will rescale back to real world coordinates after viewing the mesh) we can build the y-coordinates in sections and join them together.  We will use boundary meshing at the interfaces where the NeumannValue's are applied.  Here is the example code to show the y sections:

```
exponent = 7;
a = 100*10^-exponent;
b = 50*10^-exponent;
d = 300*10^-exponent;
y1 = 0.01;
y2 = 0.5*y1;
y3 = y2 + a;
y4 = y3 + d;
y5 = y4 + b;
Δ = y5 - y2;
pad = Ceiling[(3 l)/(2 Δ)];
{ys0, ys1, ys2, ys3, ys4, ysf} = 
  Join[{-pad }, ({y2, y3, y4, y5} - y2)/Δ, {1 + pad }];
δ = (ys4 - ys3)/4;
ϕ = δ/10;
nyElm = 500;
ρ = nyElm/(2 pad + 1);
pointsToMesh@meshGrowthByElm[ys1, ys0, 40, ϕ]
pointsToMesh@uniformPatch[ys1, ys2, ρ]
pointsToMesh@((ys3 - ys2) unitMeshGrowth2Sided [25, 1/10])
pointsToMesh@uniformPatch[ys3, ys4, ρ]
pointsToMesh@meshGrowthByElm[0, ysf - ys4, 40, ϕ]
```

[image: y meshes]

Now, we will use the helper functions to create anisotropic quad mesh (note that we put boundary layers on the x entrance and exit as well):

```
s1 = meshGrowthByElm[ys1, ys0, 40, ϕ];
s2 = uniformPatch[ys1, ys2, ρ];
s3 = ((ys3 - ys2) unitMeshGrowth2Sided [25, 1/50]);
s4 = uniformPatch[ys3, ys4, ρ];
s5 = meshGrowthByElm[0, ysf - ys4, 40, ϕ];
msh = extendMesh[s1, s2];
msh = extendMesh[msh, s3];
msh = extendMesh[msh, s4];
msh = extendMesh[msh, s5];
rpx = pointsToMesh@((ysf - ys0) unitMeshGrowth2Sided [40, 1/5]);
rpy = pointsToMesh@msh;
rp = RegionProduct[rpx, rpy]
```

[image: xy mesh]

Using scaling, we can view the intention of the mesh quite easily.  We can see where boundary layers have been applied in both the x and y directions.

## Modeling Workflow

I wrapped the remainder of the workflow in a module that is a function of one parameter only, namely the `exponent`.  The `exponent` denotes the log scale of the y dimension.  For example, $9$ would denote nanometers and $6$ would denote microns.

```
solveMuPhi[exponent_] := Module[
  {a, b, d, y1, y2, y3, y4, 
   y5, Δ, δ, ϕ, ρ, pad,
   ys0, ys1, ys2, ys3, ys4, ysf, nyElm,
   s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, rpx, rpy, rp, msh, st, sty,
   yr0, yr1, yr2, yr3, yr4, yrf, crd, inc, mesh, bcmu,
   solmu, pO2data, sigedata, A, B, bcphi, solphi, cpmu,
   cpphi, cpphizoom},
  a = 100*10^-exponent;
  b = 50*10^-exponent;
  d = 300*10^-exponent;
  y1 = 0.01;
  y2 = 0.5*y1;
  y3 = y2 + a;
  y4 = y3 + d;
  y5 = y4 + b;
  Δ = y5 - y2;
  pad = Ceiling[(3 l)/(2 Δ)];
  {ys0, ys1, ys2, ys3, ys4, ysf} = 
   Join[{-pad }, ({y2, y3, y4, y5} - y2)/Δ, {1 + pad }];
  δ = (ys4 - ys3)/4;
  ϕ = δ/10;
  nyElm = 4000;
  ρ = nyElm/(2 pad + 1);
  s1 = meshGrowthByElm[ys1, ys0, 80, ϕ];
  s2 = uniformPatch[ys1, ys2, ρ];
  s3 = ((ys3 - ys2) unitMeshGrowth2Sided [50, 1/10]);
  s4 = uniformPatch[ys3, ys4, ρ];
  s5 = meshGrowthByElm[0, ysf - ys4, 80, ϕ];
  msh = extendMesh[s1, s2];
  msh = extendMesh[msh, s3];
  msh = extendMesh[msh, s4];
  msh = extendMesh[msh, s5];
  rpx = pointsToMesh@unitMeshGrowth2Sided [50, 1/5];
  rpy = pointsToMesh@msh;
  rp = RegionProduct[rpx, rpy];
  st = ScalingTransform[{l, (2 pad + 1) Δ}];
  sty = ScalingTransform[{(2 pad + 1) Δ}];
  {yr0, yr1, yr2, yr3, yr4, yrf} = 
   Flatten@sty@
     ArrayReshape[{ys0, ys1, ys2, ys3, ys4, 
       ysf}, {Length[{ys0, ys1, ys2, ys3, ys4, ysf}], 1}];
  crd = st@ MeshCoordinates[rp];
  inc = Delete[0] /@ MeshCells[rp, 2];
  mesh = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> crd, 
    "MeshElements" -> {QuadElement[inc]}];
  mesh["Wireframe"];
  
  (*3) Solve for mu*)
  bcmu = {DirichletCondition[
     mu[x, y] == mu1, (x == 0 && yr0 < y < yrf)], 
    DirichletCondition[
     mu[x, y] == 
      mu2, (x == l && yr1 <= y <= yr2) || (x == l && 
        yr3 <= y <= yr4)]};
  solmu = 
   NDSolve[{Laplacian[mu[x, y], {x, y}] == 0, bcmu}, 
    mu, {x, y} ∈ mesh];
  
  (*4) Solve for electronic conductivity everywhere*)
  pO2data = Exp[(mu[x, y] /. solmu)/kb/T];
  
  sigedata = 
   Piecewise[{{sige0*pO2data^(-1/4), 
      0 <= x <= l - m}, {sige0*
       pO2data^(-1/4), (l - m < x <= l && 
        yr0 <= y < 
         yr1)}, {(sigeni - sige0*(pO2data /. x -> l - m)^(-1/4))/
         m*(x - (l - m)) + 
       sige0*(pO2data /. x -> l - m)^(-1/4), (l - m < x <= l && 
        y2 <= y <= y3)}, {sige0*
       pO2data^(-1/4), (l - m < x <= l && 
        yr2 < y < 
         yr3)}, {(sigeni - sige0*(pO2data /. x -> l - m)^(-1/4))/
         m*(x - (l - m)) + 
       sige0*(pO2data /. x -> l - m)^(-1/4), (l - m < x <= l && 
        yr3 <= y <= yr4)}, {sige0*
       pO2data^(-1/4), (l - m < x <= l && yr4 < y <= yrf)}}];
  
  (*5) Solve for phi*)
  A = (Irxn - sigi/(4*e)*(D[mu[x, y] /. solmu, x] /. x -> l))/(-sigi);
  B = sigi/(4*e)*(D[mu[x, y] /. solmu, x] /. 
       x -> l)/(sigi + sigedata /. x -> l - m);
  bcphi = 
   DirichletCondition[phi[x, y] == phi1, (x == 0 && yr0 < y < yrf)];
  solphi = 
   NDSolve[{Laplacian[phi[x, y], {x, y}] == 
      0 + NeumannValue[-A[[1]], (x == l && yr1 <= y <= yr2)] + 
       NeumannValue[-B[[1]], (x == l && yr3 <= y <= yr4)], bcphi}, 
    phi, {x, y} ∈ mesh];
  cpmu = ContourPlot[
    Evaluate[Exp[(mu[x, y])/kb/T] /. solmu], {x, y} ∈ mesh, 
    ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
    PlotRange -> {All, {yr1 - 2.5*10^(exponent - 7) Δ, 
       yr4 + 2.5*10^(exponent - 7) Δ}, All}, 
    Contours -> 10, PlotPoints -> All, 
    PlotLabel -> 
     Style[StringTemplate["μ Field: μ(x,y) @ exponent=``"][
       exponent], 18]];
  cpphi = 
   ContourPlot[Evaluate[phi[x, y] /. solphi], {x, y} ∈ mesh, 
    ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
    PlotRange -> {All, {yr1 - 2.0*10^(exponent - 7) Δ , 
       yr4 + 2.0*10^(exponent - 7) Δ }, All}, 
    Contours -> 20, PlotPoints -> All, 
    PlotLabel -> 
     Style[StringTemplate["ϕ Field: ϕ(x,y) @ exponent=``"][
       exponent], 18]];
  cpphizoom = 
   ContourPlot[Evaluate[phi[x, y] /. solphi], {x, y} ∈ mesh, 
    ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
    PlotRange -> {{0.75 l, 
       l}, {yr1 - 0.5*10^(exponent - 7) Δ, 
       yr4 + 0.5*10^(exponent - 7) Δ}, All}, 
    Contours -> 20, PlotPoints -> All, 
    PlotLabel -> 
     Style[StringTemplate[
        "ϕ Field Zoom: ϕ(x,y) @ exponent=``"][exponent], 
      18]];
  {mesh, solmu, solphi, cpmu, cpphi, cpphizoom}
  ]
```

## Experiments

Here, I show the technique of anisotropic quad meshing can provide high quality solutions economically and robustly over a range of three orders of magnitude.

```
{mesh, solmu, solphi, cpmu, cpphi, cpphizoom} = solveMuPhi[6];
GraphicsRow[Rasterize /@ {cpmu, cpphi, cpphizoom}, ImageSize -> 1000]
{mesh, solmu, solphi, cpmu, cpphi, cpphizoom} = solveMuPhi[7];
GraphicsRow[Rasterize /@ {cpmu, cpphi, cpphizoom}, ImageSize -> 1000]
{mesh, solmu, solphi, cpmu, cpphi, cpphizoom} = solveMuPhi[7.5];
GraphicsRow[Rasterize /@ {cpmu, cpphi, cpphizoom}, ImageSize -> 1000]
{mesh, solmu, solphi, cpmu, cpphi, cpphizoom} = solveMuPhi[8];
GraphicsRow[Rasterize /@ {cpmu, cpphi, cpphizoom}, ImageSize -> 1000]
{mesh, solmu, solphi, cpmu, cpphi, cpphizoom} = solveMuPhi[9];
GraphicsRow[Rasterize /@ {cpmu, cpphi, cpphizoom}, ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image: Simulation Results]

Comment: I will just say, beautifully compiled answer.

Comment: @IndrasisMitra Thank you very much for the acknowledgement!