# NDSolve with equation system with unknown functions defined on different domains

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, axisymmetry

Based on @xzczd's excellent [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/160105/73662) on solving an equation system with unknown functions defined on different domains, I've tried to apply the same technique to a similar system shown below:

Equations:
$$\frac{\partial c(x,z,t)}{\partial t}=D_{eff}\frac{\partial^2c(x,z,t)}{\partial x^2}+D_{eff}\frac{\partial^2c(x,z,t)}{\partial z^2}$$
$$\frac{2*len*k_x(c(l/2,z,t)-Cv(z,t))}{\pi*rad^2-len*l}-v_z\frac{\partial Cv(z,t)}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial Cv(z,t)}{\partial t}$$
Initial conditions:
$$c(x,z,0)=1$$
$$Cv(z,0)=0$$
Boundary conditions:
$$\frac{\partial c(x,z,t)}{\partial x}\Bigm|_{x=0}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial c(x,z,t)}{\partial z}\Bigm|_{z=0,len}=0$$
$$D_{eff}\frac{\partial c(x,z,t)}{\partial x}\Bigm|_{x=\pm l/2}=k_x(c(\pm l/2,z,t)-Cv(z,t))$$
New possible b.cs for $Cv$:
$$\frac{\partial Cv(z,t)}{\partial z}\Bigm|_{z=0, len}=0$$

This is the code I have so far using the function `pdetoode` in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/73662) post as well as other functions in @xzczd's post linked at the top. The main ways it differs from the post at the top is that the domain is different in the x and z directions, and obviously different boundary conditions.

```
len = 0.1; l = 0.004; rad = 0.1; vz = 0.0024; kx = 8.6*10^-4;
Deff = 8*10^-9
domainx = {-l/2, l/2}; domainz = {0, len};
T = 10000;

{eq1, eq2} = {D[c[x, z, t], t] == 
    Deff*D[c[x, z, t], {x, 2}] + 
     Deff*D[c[x, z, t], {z, 2}], 
   2*len*kx ((c2[z, t]) - Cv[z, t])/(Pi*rad^2 - len*l) - 
     vz*D[Cv[z, t], {z, 1}] == D[Cv[z, t], {t, 1}]};

{ic1, ic2} = {c[x, z, 0] == 1, Cv[z, 0] == 0};

{bc1, bc2, bc3, bc4, bc5, bc6, 
   bc7} = {(D[c[x, z, t], x] /. x -> 0) == 
    0, (Deff*D[c[x, z, t], x] /. x -> l/2) == 
    kx*((c[l/2, z, t]) - Cv2[x, z, t]), (Deff*D[c[x, z, t], x] /. 
      x -> -l/2) == 
    kx*((c[-l/2, z, t]) - Cv2[x, z, t]), (D[c[x, z, t], z] /. 
      z -> len) == 0, (D[c[x, z, t], z] /. z -> 0) == 
    0, (D[Cv[z, t], z] /. z -> 0) == 
    0, (D[Cv[z, t], z] /. z -> len) == 0};
```

Then attempting to solve using @xzczd's method (I know there are likely many problems here, especially with how I deal with the boundary conditions):

```
points = 71;
gridx = Array[# &, points, domainx];
gridz = Array[# &, points, domainz];
difforder = 4;

ptoofunc1 = 
  pdetoode[{c, Cv2}[x, z, t], t, {gridx, gridz}, difforder];
ptoofunc2 = pdetoode[{c2, Cv}[z, t], t, gridz, difforder];

del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
rule1 = Cv2[x_, z_][t_] :> Cv[z][t];
rule2 = c2[z_][t_] :> c[l/2, z][t];
ode1 = del /@ del@ptoofunc1@eq1;
ode2 = del@ptoofunc2@eq2 /. rule2;
odeic1 = ptoofunc1@ic1;
odeic2 = ptoofunc2@ic2;
odebc1 = ptoofunc1@bc1;
odebc2 = ptoofunc1@bc2 /. rule1;
odebc3 = ptoofunc1@bc3 /. rule1;
odebc4 = ptoofunc1@bc4;
odebc5 = ptoofunc1@bc5;
odebc6 = ptoofunc2@bc6;
odebc7 = ptoofunc2@bc7;

sol = NDSolveValue[{ode1, ode2, odeic1, odeic2, odebc1, odebc2, 
    odebc3, odebc4, odebc5, odebc6, odebc7}, {Outer[c, gridx, gridz], 
    Cv /@ gridz}, {t, 0, T}];

solc = rebuild[sol[[1]], {gridx, gridz}, 3];
solCv = rebuild[sol[[2]], gridz, 2];
```

EDIT: I fixed a silly mistake and am now getting this error for NDSolveValue. I'm wondering if there is a problem with how I'm dealing with the boundary conditions using `pdetoode` (which I believe is the case) or other variables and parameters, or if there's a problem in my equation setup to begin with.

```
NDSolveValue: There are fewer dependent variables, {c[-0.0002, 0.][t], c[-0.002, 0.00142857][t], c[-0.002, 0.00285714][t], <<45>>, c[-0.002, 0.0685714][t], c[-0.002, 0.07][5], <<5062>>}, than equations, so the system is overdetermined.
```

Thanks so much for reading this long post, and I'd appreciate any insight into how to fix the errors and what parameters I should modify from the post linked up top for this specific system. I'm relatively new to and still learning the ropes in Mathematica, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: To solve this system we need to add one boundary condition for `Cv`, for example  `Cv[0,t]==0`.

Comment: The left hand side of your LaTeX expression for your first equation, should be with respect to t versus x if you want it to match your _Mathematica_ code.

Comment: You may also want to look at the [Interphase Mass Transfer](https://wolfram.com/xid/07t9runjqz5n9egh7re0cg0kv359r5a-tjn9b0) section of the [Mass Transport Tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/MassTransport/MassTransport.html).  It may give you some ideas on how to setup mass transport related PDEs using the FEM.  FEM probably can solve your problem, but it may require a special mesh like I did in this answer [219140](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/219140/61809).

Comment: Boundary condition $\partial_x c(0,z,t)=0$ is useless, since it means symmetry  of solution, and it is automatically true  due to symmetry of initial condition and boundary conditions at $x=\pm l/2$. So we need some boundary condition for `Cv[0,t]`.

Comment: Thank you @TimLaska; I'll definitely look into that! And I'll also think about the boundary condition issue @Alex Trounev; thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @AlexTrounev The b.c.s at $x=\pm l/2$ doesn't indicate the solution is symmetric, I'm afraid. The $Cv$ is on the way. Even if there's no $Cv$ term, just consider Neumann b.c., the b.c. should be $\frac{∂c}{∂x}\big|_{x=l/2}=\color{red}{-}\frac{∂c}{∂x}\big|_{x=-l/2}=k$. If the b.c. at $x=0$ isn't redundant, then we need to split the domain of definition at $x=0$. Also, b.c. for $Cv$ isn't necessary if the solution of $Cv$ is a classical one, because classical solution for 1st order wave equation can be determined by one initial condition.

Comment: Thanks so much for all of your responses! If the solution turns out as it should, the solution should be symmetric about x = 0, so feel free to disregard the b.c. at x = 0 if that makes things easier

Comment: @xzczd "because classical solution for 1st order wave equation can be determined by one initial condition". Can you tell this to `NDSolve`? :) I try to solve this system with iteration method and `NDSolve` sent me message about additional bc for `Cv`.  In a static  case we need to put bc for `Cv`.  Isn't it?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I admit it's rather troublesome to handle numerically. (I tried asking [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/28744/5331) but don't get a satisfied answer. ) Adding b.c. to $Cv$ is indeed a work-around, but making the b.c. and i.c. consistent (otherwise we'll face problem like [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/145479/1871)) is also troublesome.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I've added new b.cs for Cv that I think could fit this system (I hope they are consistent with the i.cs). Thanks so much again!

Comment: @xzczd I wasn't allowed to mention you in the previous comment so I'm mentioning you now (basically I've added b.cs that could potentially work for Cv)

Comment: Version 13 has [ToGradedMesh](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToGradedMesh.html) and [ElementMeshRegionProduct](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ElementMeshRegionProduct.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Observing $D_{eff}$ and $\pi$ in the OP suggests cylinders and porous media are present.  When one starts to deviate from rectangular shapes, the FEM is superior.  Because the FEM is quite tolerant to mesh cell shape, often it is easier to extend the model to where simpler boundary conditions exist and let *Mathematica* solve for the interface.  I will demonstrate an alternate approach following the documentation for  [Modeling Mass Transport](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/MassTransport/MassTransport.html).

## Copy and Modify Operator Functions

The tutorials and verification tests provide helper functions that allow you to generate a well formed FEM operator.  We will reproduce these functions here.  Furthermore, we will adapt the functions for generating an axisymmetric operator from the [Heat Transfer Verification Tests](https://wolfram.com/xid/0ff96riwpp6gsggq26cfje31a9m4cps36kvv3fye8-u8i85k) and also include porosity as shown below:

```
(* From Mass Transport Tutorial *)
Options[MassTransportModel] = {"ModelForm" -> "NonConservative"};
MassTransportModel[c_, X_List, d_, Velocity_, Rate_, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{V, R, a = d},
  V = If[Velocity === "NoFlow", 0, Velocity];
  R = If[Rate === "NoReaction", 0, Rate];
  If[ FreeQ[a, _?VectorQ], a = a*IdentityMatrix[Length[X]]];
  If[ VectorQ[a], a = DiagonalMatrix[a]];
  (* Note the - sign in the operator *)
  a = PiecewiseExpand[Piecewise[{{-a, True}}]];
  If[ OptionValue["ModelForm"] === "Conservative", 
   Inactive[Div][a.Inactive[Grad][c, X], X] + Inactive[Div][V*c, X] - 
    R, Inactive[Div][a.Inactive[Grad][c, X], X] + 
    V.Inactive[Grad][c, X] - R]]

Options[TimeMassTransportModel] = Options[MassTransportModel];
TimeMassTransportModel[c_, TimeVar_, X_List, d_, Velocity_, Rate_, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 D[c, {TimeVar, 1}] + MassTransportModel[c, X, d, Velocity, Rate, opts]

(* Adapted from Heat Transfer Verification Tests *)
MassTransportModelAxisymmetric[c_, {r_, z_}, d_, Velocity_, Rate_, 
  Porosity_ : "NoPorosity"] :=
 Module[{V, R, P},
  P = If[Porosity === "NoPorosity", 1, Porosity];
  V = If[Velocity === "NoFlow", 0, Velocity.Inactive[Grad][c, {r, z}]];
  R = If[Rate === "NoReaction", 0, P Rate];
  1/r*D[-P*d*r*D[c, r], r] + D[-P*d*D[c, z], z] + V - R]

TimeMassTransportModelAxisymmetric[c_, TimeVar_, {r_, z_}, d_, 
  Velocity_, Rate_, Porosity_ : "NoPorosity"] :=
 Module[{P},
  P = If[Porosity === "NoPorosity", 1, Porosity];
  P D[c, {TimeVar, 1}] + 
   MassTransportModelAxisymmetric[c, {r, z}, d, Velocity, Rate, 
    Porosity]]
```

## Estimating the Timescale

Assuming the dimensions are SI, you have a high aspect ratio geometry, small radius (2 mm), and relatively large $D_{eff}$ for a liquid.  Generally, it is not a good idea to simulate greatly beyond the fully responded time as instabilities can creep in.

Let's set up a simple axisymmetric model with the following parameters:

```
rinner = 0.002;
len = 0.1;
(* No gradients in the z-direction so make len small for now *)
len = rinner/5;
tend = 200;
Deff = 8*10^-9;
(* Porosity *)
epsilon = 0.5;
```

We will create an operator, initialize the domain to a concentration of 1, impart a DirichletCondition of 0 on the outer wall (named rinner for now), and create a couple of visualizations.

```
(* Set up the operator *)
op = TimeMassTransportModelAxisymmetric[c[t, r, z], t, {r, z}, Deff, 
   "NoFlow", "NoReaction", epsilon];
(* Create Domain *)
Ω2Daxi = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {rinner, len}];
(* Setup Boundary and Initial Conditions *)
Subscript[Γ, wall] = 
  DirichletCondition[c[t, r, z] == 0, r == rinner];
ic = c[0, r, z] == 1;
(* Solve PDE *)
cfun = NDSolveValue[{op == 0, Subscript[Γ, wall], ic}, 
   c, {t, 0, tend}, {r, z} ∈ Ω2Daxi];
(* Setup ContourPlot Visualiztion *)
cRange = MinMax[cfun["ValuesOnGrid"]];
legendBar = 
  BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", cRange(*{0,1}*)}, 10, 
   LegendLabel -> 
    Style["[\!\(\*FractionBox[\(mol\), SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \
\(3\)]]\)]", Opacity[0.6`]]];
options = {PlotRange -> cRange, 
   ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", cRange}], 
   ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.1`], ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
   Contours -> 30, PlotPoints -> 100, FrameLabel -> {"r", "z"}, 
   PlotLabel -> Style["Concentration Field: c(t,r,z)", 18], 
   AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 250};
nframes = 30;
frames = Table[
   Legended[
    ContourPlot[cfun[t, r, z], {r, z} ∈ Ω2Daxi,
      Evaluate[options]], legendBar], {t, 0, tend, tend/nframes}];
frames = Rasterize[#1, "Image", ImageResolution -> 100] & /@ frames;
ListAnimate[frames, SaveDefinitions -> True, ControlPlacement -> Top]
(* Setup Fake 3D Visualization *)
nframes = 40;
axisymPlot = 
  Function[{t}, 
   Legended[
    RegionPlot3D[
     x^2 + y^2 <= (rinner)^2 && 
      0 <= PlanarAngle[{0, 0} -> {{rinner, 0}, {x, y}}] <= (4 π)/
       3, {x, -rinner, rinner}, {y, -rinner, rinner}, {z, 0, len}, 
     PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotPoints -> 50, 
     PlotLegends -> None, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", Mesh -> None, 
     AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
     ColorFunction -> 
      Function[{x, y, z}, 
       Which[x^2 + y^2 >= (rinner)^2, Blue, True, 
        ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", cRange}][
         cfun[t, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], z]]]], ImageSize -> Medium, 
     PlotLabel -> 
      Style[StringTemplate["Concentration Field at t = `` [s]"][
        ToString@PaddedForm[t, {3, 4}]], 12]], legendBar]];
framesaxi = Table[axisymPlot[t], {t, 0, tend, tend/nframes}];
framesaxi = 
  Rasterize[#1, "Image", ImageResolution -> 100] & /@ framesaxi;
ListAnimate[framesaxi, SaveDefinitions -> True, 
 ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

[image: Bare Pipe]

[image: Bare Pipe 3D]

The system responds in about 200 s, indicating that 10,000 s end time may be excessive for a small diameter system.

## Modeling Flow

Constant convective heat/mass transfer film coefficients only apply to fully developed thermal and flow boundary layers.  Indeed the film coefficients are infinite at the entrance.  Instead of making the assumption that the film coefficients are constant, I will demonstrate work flow that allows the FEM solver do the heavy lifting of managing the transport at the interface.

### Boundary Layer Meshing

If the mesh is too coarse, the fluxes across interfaces are overpredicted.  Therefore, one requires boundary layer meshing to reduce the overprediction error.  Unfortunately, you have to roll-your-own boundary layer meshing for now.

#### Define Quad Mesh Helper Functions

Here some helper functions that can be useful in defining a anisotropic quad mesh.

```
(* Load Required Package *)
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
(* Define Some Helper Functions For Structured Quad Mesh*)
pointsToMesh[data_] :=
  MeshRegion[Transpose[{data}], 
   Line@Table[{i, i + 1}, {i, Length[data] - 1}]];
unitMeshGrowth[n_, r_] := 
 Table[(r^(j/(-1 + n)) - 1.)/(r - 1.), {j, 0, n - 1}]
unitMeshGrowth2Sided [nhalf_, r_] := (1 + Union[-Reverse@#, #])/2 &@
  unitMeshGrowth[nhalf, r]
meshGrowth[x0_, xf_, n_, r_] := (xf - x0) unitMeshGrowth[n, r] + x0
firstElmHeight[x0_, xf_, n_, r_] := 
 Abs@First@Differences@meshGrowth[x0, xf, n, r]
lastElmHeight[x0_, xf_, n_, r_] := 
 Abs@Last@Differences@meshGrowth[x0, xf, n, r]
findGrowthRate[x0_, xf_, n_, fElm_] := 
 Quiet@Abs@
   FindRoot[firstElmHeight[x0, xf, n, r] - fElm, {r, 1.0001, 100000}, 
     Method -> "Brent"][[1, 2]]
meshGrowthByElm[x0_, xf_, n_, fElm_] := 
 N@Sort@Chop@meshGrowth[x0, xf, n, findGrowthRate[x0, xf, n, fElm]]
meshGrowthByElmSym[x0_, xf_, n_, fElm_] := 
 With[{mid = Mean[{x0, xf}]}, 
  Union[meshGrowthByElm[mid, x0, n, fElm], 
   meshGrowthByElm[mid, xf, n, fElm]]]
reflectRight[pts_] := With[{rt = ReflectionTransform[{1}, {Last@pts}]},
  Union[pts, Flatten[rt /@ Partition[pts, 1]]]]
reflectLeft[pts_] := 
 With[{rt = ReflectionTransform[{-1}, {First@pts}]},
  Union[pts, Flatten[rt /@ Partition[pts, 1]]]]
extendMesh[mesh_, newmesh_] := Union[mesh, Max@mesh + newmesh]
uniformPatch[p1_, p2_, ρ_] := 
 With[{d = p2 - p1}, Subdivide[0, d, 2 + Ceiling[d ρ]]]
```

#### Build a Two Region Mesh (Porous/Fluid).

The following workflow builds a 2D annular mesh with green porous inner region and a red outer fluid region.  I've adjusted some parameters to slow things down a bit to be seen in the animations.

[image: Two Region Mesh]

#### Annular Velocity Profile for Laminar Newtonian Flow

To make things a bit more interesting, we will create flow field for axial laminar flow in the annular region based on this diagram.

[image: Annular Flow Diagram]

For laminar flow in an annulus, the following equation for the velocity profile may be used:

```
Vannular[vavgz_, Ro_, κ_][r_] := 
 vavgz (2 (Ro^2 (-1 + κ^2) Log[Ro/r] + (-r^2 + Ro^2) Log[
       1/κ]))/(
  Ro^2 (-1 + κ^2 + (1 + κ^2) Log[1/κ]))
Plot[Vannular[vzfluid, router, kappa][r], {r, kappa router, router}]
```

[image: Annular Flow Field]

#### Setup Region Dependent PDE and Apply it to the Mesh

The following workflow will region dependent properties to the mesh based on the previously defined element markers, solve the PDE system, and create two animations.

```
(* Region Dependent Diffusion, Porosity, and Velocity *)
diff = Evaluate[
   Piecewise[{{Deff, ElementMarker == reg["porous"]}, {Dfluid, 
      True}}]];
porous = Evaluate[
   Piecewise[{{epsilon, ElementMarker == reg["porous"]}, {1, True}}]];
velocity = 
  Evaluate[Piecewise[{{{{0, 0}}, 
      ElementMarker == 
       reg["porous"]}, {{{0, Vannular[vzfluid, router, kappa][r]}}, 
      True}}]];
(* Create Operator *)
op = TimeMassTransportModelAxisymmetric[c[t, r, z], t, {r, z}, diff, 
   velocity, "NoReaction", porous];
(* Set up BCs and ICs *)
Subscript[Γ, in] = 
  DirichletCondition[c[t, r, z] == 0, z == 0 && r >= rinner];
ic = c[0, r, z] == 1;
(* Solve *)
cfun = NDSolveValue[{op == 0, Subscript[Γ, in], ic}, 
   c, {t, 0, tend}, {r, z} ∈ mesh];
(* Display ContourPlot Animation*)
cRange = MinMax[cfun["ValuesOnGrid"]];
legendBar = 
  BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", cRange(*{0,1}*)}, 10, 
   LegendLabel -> 
    Style[
     "[\!\(\*FractionBox[\(mol\), SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \(3\)]]\)]", 
     Opacity[0.6`]]];
options = {PlotRange -> cRange, 
   ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", cRange}], 
   ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.1`], ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
   Contours -> 20, PlotPoints -> All, FrameLabel -> {"r", "z"}, 
   PlotLabel -> 
    Style["Concentration Field: c(t,r,z)", 
     18],(*AspectRatio\[Rule]Automatic,*)AspectRatio -> 1, 
   ImageSize -> 250};
nframes = 30;
frames = Table[
   Legended[
    ContourPlot[cfun[t, r, z], {r, z} ∈ mesh, 
     Evaluate[options]], legendBar], {t, 0, tend, tend/nframes}];
frames = Rasterize[#1, "Image", ImageResolution -> 100] & /@ frames;
ListAnimate[frames, SaveDefinitions -> True]
 (* Display RegionPlot3D Animation *)
nframes = 40;
axisymPlot2 = 
  Function[{t}, 
   Legended[
    RegionPlot3D[
     x^2 + y^2 <= (router)^2 && 
      0 <= PlanarAngle[{0, 0} -> {{router, 0}, {x, y}}] <= (4 π)/
       3, {x, -router, router}, {y, -router, router}, {z, 0, len}, 
     PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotPoints -> 50, 
     PlotLegends -> None, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", Mesh -> None, 
     AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
     ColorFunction -> 
      Function[{x, y, z}, 
       Which[x^2 + y^2 >= (router)^2, Blue, True, 
        ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", cRange}][
         cfun[t, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], z]]]], ImageSize -> Medium, 
     PlotLabel -> 
      Style[StringTemplate["Concentration Field at t = `` [s]"][
        ToString@PaddedForm[t, {3, 4}]], 12]], legendBar]];
framesaxi2 = Table[axisymPlot2[t], {t, 0, tend, tend/nframes}];
framesaxi2 = 
  Rasterize[#1, "Image", ImageResolution -> 95] & /@ framesaxi2;
ListAnimate[framesaxi2, SaveDefinitions -> True, 
 ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

[image: 2D Annular Flow]

[image: 3D Annular Flow]

The simulation produces qualitatively reasonable results.  The Mass Transport Tutorial also shows how to add an equilibrium condition between the porous and fluid phases by adding a thin interface.  I also demonstrated this principle in my Wolfram Community post [Modeling jump conditions in interphase mass transfer](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1551098).

## Conclusion

By extending the model to where simple boundary conditions exist, we have obviated the need for complex boundary conditions.

## Appendix

As per the OP request in the comments, the bullet list below shows several examples where I have used anisotropic quad meshing to capture sharp interfaces that would otherwise be very computationally expensive.  The code is functional, but not optimal and some of the functions have been modified over time.  Use at your own risk

1. 2D-Stationary

   - [Mathematica vs. MATLAB: why am I getting different results for PDE with non-constant boundary condition?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/222947/61809)
   - [Improving mesh and NDSolve solution convergence](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/226561/61809)
2. 2D-Transient

   - [Controlling dynamic time step size in NDSolveValue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/204907/61809)
   - [How to model diffusion through a membrane?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/219140/61809)
3. 3D-Stationary

   - [How to Improve FEM Solution with NDSolve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/220123/61809)

If you have access to other tools, such as COMSOL, that have boundary layer functionality, you can import meshes via the [FEMAddOns resource function](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/FEMAddOnsInstall).  It will not work for 3D meshes which require additional element types like prisms and pyramids that are not currently supported in *Mathematica's* FEM.

Comment: Thank you so much for your extremely detailed and clear answer! I have decided to go with this approach. Besides your answer on modeling jump conditions in interphase mass transfer, do you recommend other resources for understanding and learning how to implement the quad mesh?

Comment: @Jan I have used the anisotropic quad meshing on many occasions.  It is not necessarily trivial to implement, but it can solve many problems that are a result of the mesh and not the equations.  My main inspiration came from this [RegionProduct Example of a Tensor Grid](https://wolfram.com/xid/0rs5ccudm-eqv31q).  If you can construct a valid Region, then many of the typical meshing problems (e.g., duplicate vertices and node ordering go away).  Would it help to append my answer with some links to where I have used quad meshing?

Comment: Yes, that would be very helpful. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Jan I added some examples of quad meshing.

Comment: Thanks so much again! I tried setting up a quad mesh and solving based on the great workflow you provided, but I'm getting the error ```NDSolve: The arguments should be ordered consistently.``` for the evaluation of ```cfun```. Would you happen to have suggestions as to what might be causing this, or would it be easier if I just made a separate post to explain everything?

Comment: @Jan Generally, that error is a result of the ordering of the temporal and spatial variables either in the dependent variable, c[t,r,z], or the ordering of the domain specification.  To be consistent with the documented examples, I always use temporal, spatial list like $NDSolveValue[{op == 0, \Gamma in, ic}, c\begin{bmatrix}
{\color{Red} t},{\color{Blue} r,z}
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{Bmatrix}
{{\color{Red} t}, 0, 
  tend}
\end{Bmatrix}, \begin{Bmatrix}
{\color{Blue} r, z}
\end{Bmatrix} \epsilon \   mesh]$.  If this doesn't help, you could pose a new question.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! After restarting the kernel that problem no longer happens, but I'm still having some trouble as I explain in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/228080/73662. Thanks again for all of your help and guidance!

Comment: @Jan I will look at it tonight or tomorrow and see if I can help.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 3):

I try to solve this system with using `NDSolve` and method of iterations, and with additional bc for `Cv2` consistent with initial condition. Numerical solution converges for a short time `t=40`. But for required `T = 10000` code runs forever. It takes 5 iterations only to get solution:

```
len = 0.1; l = 0.004; rad = 0.1; vz = 0.0024; kx = 8.6*10^-4;
Deff = 8*10^-9;
domainx = {-l/2, l/2}; domainz = {0, len}; reg = 
 Rectangle[{-l/2, 0}, {l/2, len}];
T = 20;



Cv2[0][z_, t_] := 0; a = 2*len*kx/(Pi*rad^2 - len*l);

Do[C2 = NDSolveValue[{D[c[x, z, t], t] - Deff*(D[c[x, z, t], {x, 2}] + 
      D[c[x, z, t], {z, 2}]) == 
     NeumannValue[-kx*((c[x, z, t]) - Cv2[i - 1][z, t]), 
      x == -l/2 || x == l/2], c[x, z, 0] == 1}, c, 
   Element[{x, z}, reg], {t, 0, T}]; 
 Cv2[i] = NDSolveValue[{ 
    a ((C2[l/2, z, t]) - Cv[z, t]) - vz*D[Cv[z, t], {z, 1}] == 
     D[Cv[z, t], {t, 1}], Cv[z, 0] == 0, Cv[0, t] == 0(*If[t>10^-2,C2[
    l/2,0,t]-Deff/kx Derivative[1,0,0][C2][l/2,0,t],0]*)}, 
   Cv, {z, 0, len}, {t, 0, T}];, {i, 1, 5}]
```

Visualization of `c` and `Cv`

```
{Plot3D[C2[x, z, T], Element[{x, z}, reg], Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotPoints -> 50, Boxed -> False, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic], 
 Plot3D[C2[x, len/2, t], {x, -l/2, l/2}, {t, 0, T}, Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotPoints -> 50, Boxed -> False, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic]}

Plot3D[Cv2[5][z, t], {z, 0, len}, {t, 0, T}, Mesh -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotPoints -> 50, Boxed -> False, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Thank you so much -- this was extremely helpful! I had a few questions: 1) in the ```C2``` equation, I believe should it be minus ```Deff*D[c[x, z, t], {z, 2}]``` instead of plus, right? 2) why did you use negative instead of positive ```kx``` in the ```NeumannValue```? (Sorry if those are dumb questions, as I'm still pretty new to Mathematica) and thanks again!

Comment: Also, why wouldn't the ```NeumannValue``` be ```-kx*((c[x, z, t]) - Cv2[i - 1][z, t]``` divided by ```Deff```?

Comment: @Jan Sorry, I have corrected code as `Deff(D[c[x, z, t], {x, 2}] + D[c[x, z, t], {z, 2}])`.  Boundary condition with `NeumannValue[]' is a very trike in Mathematica.  See tutorial for using it.

Comment: @Jan I just want to emphasize again the original b.c. in $x$ direction given by you won't lead to symmetric solution. Alex has actually modified your b.c. at $x=\pm l/2$. (The normal vector is $(1,0)$ at $x = l/2$, and $(-1,0)$ at $x = -l/2$. ) You may refer to the **Details** section of document of `NeumannValue` for more info.

Comment: @xzczd thanks for pointing that out! Would you be able to elaborate on how exactly the b.c was modified (I've read the documentation for ```NeumannValue``` and still don't understand it too well)?

Comment: @Jan Try substituting the solution back into the b.c. and plotting it, then you'll see how the sign changes.

Comment: @xzczd thank you! How would one modify the ```NeumannValue``` so that it matches the original b.c.?

Comment: @Jan If you try to solve problem of cooling some hot specimen by the cool fluid around, then my  code is right implementation of b.c. for this case as shown picture.