# Problem Encountered when Solving a System Consisting of Two PDEs and an ODE in a Semi-NDSolve-based Approach

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, integral-equations, modeling

This is a continuation for [question 300522](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/300522/specifying-prescribed-mesh-to-solve-for-a-system-consisting-of-two-pdes-and-an-o).

Firstly, I have changed the equation for $C_{2\text{b}}^* $ in my system. The updated $C_{2\text{b}}^* $ is expressed as below:

$$
\begin{equation} 
C_{2\text{b}}^* = C_{F}^* \frac{C_{2\text{f}} N_A v_w}{C_{2\text{f}} N_A v_w +\exp{\beta \Delta U} } 
\end{equation}
$$

For a clearer context, I am basically solving for a transient Poisson-Nernst-Planck (PNP) system. It consists of three major equations: one transport PDE for `c1f` (co-ion), one transport PDE for `c2f` (counter-ion), and one poisson equation (the ODE) that governs the electrical potential `phi` induced by the salt ion and membrane fixed charge group. Additionally, I also consider the binding of the counter-ion at the membrane fixed charge, termed as `c2b` or $C_{2\text{b}}^* $.

The computational domain consists of the salt solution (0<`xStar`<3) and the membrane (3<`xStar`<6). Here, I consider one property difference between the salt solution and the membrane, which is the existence of fixed-charge `cF[xStar]` in the membrane, while none in the salt solution. This is a piecewise function that is approximated by `xStar`-dependent hyperbolic tangent function. To note, it is expected to have a steep change in mathematical solution value at the solution-membrane interface, and I believe this might be one of the possible origins for the solving issue.

I believe that a logically-sound numerical solution should exist for my system. This is because I managed to obtain the solution at `tStar`=0 and steady state.

My code to obtain solution at `tStar`=0:

```
(*Phi Solution for Initial Condition*)
ClearAll["Global`*"]

(*Parameters*)
kB = 1.380649*10^-23;
absTemp = 298.15;
beta = 1/(kB*absTemp);
eps0 = 8.8541878128*10^(-12);
eps = 78.6;
e = 1.60217663*10^(-19);
nA = 6.02214076*10^(23);
dfsvt = 1.33*10^(-9);
xRef = 10*10^(-6);
tRef = 10*10^(-2);
xStarMem0 = 3;
xStarMemMid = 6;
cSaltBar = 1500;(*mol/m3*)
cFVal = 300;(*mol/m3*)
cF[xStar_] = cFVal/2*(Tanh[15*(xStar - xStarMem0)] + 1);
z1 = -1;
z2 = 1;
deltaU = -1/beta;
vW = 30*10^(-30);

(*BCs*)
phiDirichBC = phi[0] == 0;
phiNuemBC = NeumannValue[0, xStar == xStarMemMid];

(*IC Equations*)
c1fIC[xStar_] = -z2/z1*cSaltBar/2*(Tanh[-15*(xStar - xStarMem0)] + 1); 
c2fIC[xStar_] = cSaltBar/2*(Tanh[-15*(xStar - xStarMem0)] + 1); 
c2bIC[xStar_] = 
  cF[xStar]*(nA*c2fIC[xStar]*vW)/(nA*c2fIC[xStar]*vW + 
      Exp[beta*deltaU]);
elctrcTrnsprtIC = 
  D[eps*eps0/(xRef^2*e*nA)*D[phi[xStar], xStar], 
    xStar] == -(-cF[xStar] + z2*(c2fIC[xStar] + c2bIC[xStar]) + 
       z1*c1fIC[xStar]) + phiNuemBC;

(*NDSolve*)
totalSol = 
  NDSolve[{elctrcTrnsprtIC, phiDirichBC}, {phi}, {xStar, 0, 
    xStarMemMid}, 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
       "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 
          0.0001}}}];
(*Define the concentration function concentration[r,t]*)
phiSolIC[xStar_] = phi[xStar] /. totalSol[[1]];

(*Solution Plotting*)
Plot[Evaluate@phiSolIC[xStar], {xStar, 0, xStarMemMid}, 
 PlotRange -> All, FrameLabel -> {"xStar", "Elec Pot (V)"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Electrical Potential, Initial"]
Plot[c1fIC[xStar], {xStar, 0, xStarMemMid}, PlotRange -> {0, Full}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"xStar", "Conc (mol/m3)"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Free Co Ion, Initial"]
Plot[c2fIC[xStar], {xStar, 0, xStarMemMid}, PlotRange -> {0, Full}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"xStar", "Conc (mol/m3)"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Free Ct Ion, Initial"]
Plot[c2bIC[xStar], {xStar, 0, xStarMemMid}, PlotRange -> {0, Full}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"xStar", "Conc (mol/m3)"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Binded Ct Ion, Initial"]
```

My code to obtain steady-state solution:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
(*Parameters*)
kB = 1.380649*10^-23; 
absTemp = 298.15;
beta = 1/(kB*absTemp);
eps0 = 8.8541878128*10^(-12);
eps = 78.6;
e = 1.60217663*10^(-19);
nA = 6.02214076*10^(23);
dfsvt = 1.33*10^(-9);
xRef = 10*10^(-6);
tRef = 10*10^(-2);
xStarMem0 = 3;
xStarMemMid = 6;
cSaltBar = 1500;(*mol/m3*)
cFVal = 300;(*mol/m3*)
cF[xStar_] = cFVal/2*(Tanh[15*(xStar - xStarMem0)] + 1); 
z1 = -1;
z2 = 1;
deltaU = -1/beta;
vW = 30*10^(-30);

(*BCs*)
phiDirichBC = phi[0] == 0;
phiNuemBC = NeumannValue[0, xStar == xStarMemMid];

(*Equations*)
c1f[xStar_] = -z2/z1*cSaltBar*Exp[-beta*z1*e*phi[xStar]] ;
c2f[xStar_] = cSaltBar*Exp[-beta*z2*e*phi[xStar]] ;
c2b[xStar_] = 
  cF[xStar]*(nA*c2f[xStar]*vW)/(nA*c2f[xStar]*vW + Exp[beta*deltaU]);
elctrcTrnsprt = 
  D[eps*eps0/(xRef^2*e*nA)*D[phi[xStar], xStar], 
    xStar] == -(-cF[xStar] + z2*(c2f[xStar] + c2b[xStar]) + 
       z1*c1f[xStar]) + phiNuemBC;

(*Input Parameter Plotting*)
Plot[cF[x], {x, 0, xStarMemMid}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLabel -> "Fixed Charge Distribution (mol/m3)"]

(*NDSolve*)
totalSol = 
  NDSolve[{elctrcTrnsprt, phiDirichBC}, {phi}, {xStar, 0, 
    xStarMemMid}, 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
       "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0001}}}];

(*Define the concentration function concentration[r,t]*)
phiSol[xStar_] = phi[xStar] /. totalSol[[1]];

(*Solution Plotting*)
Plot[Evaluate@phiSol[xStar], {xStar, 0, xStarMemMid}, 
 PlotRange -> All, FrameLabel -> {"xStar", "Elec Pot (V)"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Electrical Potential, steady"]
Plot[c1f[xStar] /. {phi -> phiSol}, {xStar, 0, xStarMemMid}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, All}, FrameLabel -> {"xStar", "Conc (mol/m3)"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Free Co Ion, steady"]
Plot[c2f[xStar] /. {phi -> phiSol}, {xStar, 0, xStarMemMid}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, All}, FrameLabel -> {"xStar", "Conc (mol/m3)"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Free Ct Ion, steady"]
Plot[c2b[xStar] /. {phi -> phiSol}, {xStar, 0, xStarMemMid}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, All}, FrameLabel -> {"xStar", "Conc (mol/m3)"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Binded Ct Ion, steady"]
```

To solve the Poisson-Nernst-Planck in transient state, I have adopted the [Method of Lines](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html) approach from [question 78493](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78493/pde-of-real-world-system-integral-boundary-condition/78564#78564), which is commonly used to solve for [integro-differential equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/186762/ndsolvecoupled-pdes-initial-boundary-value-problem-unreasonable-insufficien?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [PDE-ODE-coupled system](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163923/variation-of-heat-equation-with-guessed-initial-condition/163956#163956). To discretize my system, I am using the `pdetoode` function from the accepted answer of [question 127980](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127980/dynamic-euler-bernoulli-beam-equation/127997#127997). Not only that, I also differentiated both sides of my ODE wrt `timeStar`, making it a PDE. Subsequently, I included the initial condition for `phi`, which is the variable to be solved from my ODE.

Here is the code for `pdetoode`:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Clear[fdd, pdetoode, tooderule, pdetoae, diffbc, rebuild]
fdd[{}, grid_, value_, order_, periodic_] := value;
fdd[a__] := NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative@a;

pdetoode[funcvalue_List, rest__] := 
  pdetoode[(Alternatives @@ Head /@ funcvalue) @@ funcvalue[[1]], 
   rest];
pdetoode[{func__}[var__], rest__] := 
  pdetoode[Alternatives[func][var], rest];
pdetoode[front__, grid_?VectorQ, o_Integer, periodic_ : False] := 
  pdetoode[front, {grid}, o, periodic];

pdetoode[func_[var__], time_, {grid : {__} ..}, o_Integer, 
   periodic : True | False | {(True | False) ..} : False] := 
  With[{pos = Position[{var}, time][[1, 1]]}, 
   With[{bound = #[[{1, -1}]] & /@ {grid}, 
     pat = Repeated[_, {pos - 1}], 
     spacevar = Alternatives @@ Delete[{var}, pos]}, 
    With[{coordtoindex = 
       Function[coord, 
        MapThread[
         Piecewise[{{1, PossibleZeroQ[# - #2[[1]]]}, {-1, 
             PossibleZeroQ[# - #2[[-1]]]}}, All] &, {coord, bound}]]},
      tooderule@
      Flatten@{((u : func) | 
            Derivative[dx1 : pat, dt_, dx2___][(u : func)])[x1 : pat, 
          t_, x2___] :> (Sow@coordtoindex@{x1, x2};
          
          fdd[{dx1, dx2}, {grid}, 
           Outer[Derivative[dt][u@##]@t &, grid], 
           "DifferenceOrder" -> o, 
           PeriodicInterpolation -> periodic]), 
        inde : spacevar :> 
         With[{i = Position[spacevar, inde][[1, 1]]}, 
          Outer[Slot@i &, grid]]}]]];

tooderule[rule_][pde_List] := tooderule[rule] /@ pde;
tooderule[rule_]@Equal[a_, b_] := 
  Equal[tooderule[rule][a - b], 0] //. 
   eqn : HoldPattern@Equal[_, _] :> Thread@eqn;
tooderule[rule_][expr_] := #[[Sequence @@ #2[[1, 1]]]] & @@ 
  Reap[expr /. rule]

pdetoae[funcvalue_List, rest__] := 
  pdetoae[(Alternatives @@ Head /@ funcvalue) @@ funcvalue[[1]], rest];
pdetoae[{func__}[var__], rest__] := 
  pdetoae[Alternatives[func][var], rest];

pdetoae[func_[var__], rest__] := 
 Module[{t}, 
  Function[
     pde, #[pde /. {Derivative[d__][u : func][inde__] :> 
          Derivative[d, 0][u][inde, t], (u : func)[inde__] :> 
          u[inde, t]}] /. (u : func)[i__][t] :> u[i]] &@
   pdetoode[func[var, t], t, rest]]

diffbc[rst__][a : _List | _Equal] := diffbc[rst] /@ a
diffbc[dvar : {t_, order_} | (t_) .., sf_ : 0][a_] /; sf =!= t := 
 sf a + D[a, dvar]

rebuild[funcarray_, grid_?VectorQ, timeposition_ : 1] := 
 rebuild[funcarray, {grid}, timeposition]

rebuild[funcarray_, grid_, timeposition_?Negative] := 
 rebuild[funcarray, grid, Range[Length@grid + 1][[timeposition]]]

rebuild[funcarray_, grid_, timeposition_ : 1] /; 
  Dimensions@funcarray === Length /@ grid := 
 With[{depth = Length@grid}, 
  ListInterpolation[
     Transpose[
      Map[Developer`ToPackedArray@#["ValuesOnGrid"] &, #, {depth}], 
      Append[Delete[Range[depth + 1], timeposition], timeposition]], 
     Insert[grid, Flatten[#][[1]]["Coordinates"][[1]], 
      timeposition]] &@funcarray]
```

Below is my code:

```
(*Parameters*)
kB = 1.380649*10^-23; 
absTemp = 298.15;
beta = 1/(kB*absTemp);
eps0 = 8.8541878128*10^(-12);
eps = 78.6;
e = 1.60217663*10^(-19);
nA = 6.02214076*10^(23);
dfsvt = 1.33*10^(-9);
xRef = 10*10^(-6);
tRef = 10*10^(-2);
xStarMem0 = 3;
xStarMemMid = 6;
cSaltBar = 1500;(*mol/m3*)
cFVal = 300;(*mol/m3*)
cF[xStar_] = cFVal/2*(Tanh[15*(xStar - xStarMem0)] + 1); 
z1 = -1;
z2 = 1;
deltaU = -1/beta;
vW = 30*10^(-30);

(*Governing Equations*)
c2b[xStar_, tStar_] = 
  cF[xStar]*(nA*c2f[xStar, tStar]*vW)/(nA*c2f[xStar, tStar]*vW + 
      Exp[beta*deltaU]);
c1Trnsprt = 
  D[c1f[xStar, tStar], tStar] == 
   tRef/(xRef^2)*
    D[dfsvt*(D[c1f[xStar, tStar], xStar] + 
        beta*z1*e*c1f[xStar, tStar]*D[phi[xStar, tStar], xStar]), 
     xStar];
c2Trnsprt = 
  D[c2f[xStar, tStar], tStar] == 
   tRef/(xRef^2)*
     D[dfsvt*(D[c2f[xStar, tStar], xStar] + 
         beta*z2*e*c2f[xStar, tStar]*D[phi[xStar, tStar], xStar]), 
      xStar] - D[c2b[xStar, tStar], tStar];
elctrcTrnsprt = 
  D[D[eps*eps0/(xRef^2*e*nA)*D[phi[xStar, tStar], xStar], xStar], 
    tStar] == -D[(-cF[xStar] + 
       z2*(c2f[xStar, tStar] + c2b[xStar, tStar]) + 
       z1*c1f[xStar, tStar]), tStar];

(*Phi Solution for Initial Condition*)
(*IC Equations*)
c1fICsol[xStar_] = -z2/z1*
   cSaltBar/2*(Tanh[-15*(xStar - xStarMem0)] + 1); 
c2fICsol[xStar_] = cSaltBar/2*(Tanh[-15*(xStar - xStarMem0)] + 1); 
c2bICsol[xStar_] = 
  cF[xStar]*(nA*c2fICsol[xStar]*vW)/(nA*c2fICsol[xStar]*vW + 
      Exp[beta*deltaU]);
elctrcTrnsprtIC = 
  D[eps*eps0/(xRef^2*e*nA)*D[phiIC[xStar], xStar], 
    xStar] == -(-cF[xStar] + z2*(c2fICsol[xStar] + c2bICsol[xStar]) + 
       z1*c1fICsol[xStar]) + phiICNuemBC;
(*BCs*)
phiICDirichBC = phiIC[0] == 0;
phiICNuemBC = NeumannValue[0, xStar == xStarMemMid];
(*NDSolve*)
totalSol = 
  NDSolve[{elctrcTrnsprtIC, phiICDirichBC}, {phiIC}, {xStar, 0, 
    xStarMemMid}, 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
       "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 
          0.0001}}}(*,{xStar}\[Element]xStarMesh*)];
(*Define the concentration function concentration[r,t]*)
phiSolIC[xStar_] = phiIC[xStar] /. totalSol[[1]]

(*BCs and ICs*)
c1fIC = c1f[xStar, 0] == -z2/z1*
    cSaltBar/2*(Tanh[-15*(xStar - xStarMem0)] + 1); 
c1fDirichBC = c1f[0, tStar] == -z2/z1*cSaltBar;
c1fNuemBC = Derivative[1, 0][c1f][xStarMemMid, tStar] == 0;
c2fIC = c2f[xStar, 0] == 
   cSaltBar/2*(Tanh[-15*(xStar - xStarMem0)] + 1); 
c2fDirichBC = c2f[0, tStar] == cSaltBar;
c2fNuemBC = Derivative[1, 0][c2f][xStarMemMid, tStar] == 0;
phiIC = phi[xStar, 0] == phiSolIC[xStar];
phiDirichBC = phi[0, tStar] == 0;
phiNuemBC = Derivative[1, 0][phi][xStarMemMid, tStar] == 0;


(*Spatial Discretization of the Governing Eqns, BCs, and ICs*)
points = 25; (*Intervals is points - 1*)
domain = {0, xStarMemMid};
grid = Array[# &, points, domain];
difforder = 1;
ptoofunc = 
  pdetoode[{c1f, c2f, phi}[xStar, tStar], tStar, grid, difforder];
removeredundant = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
dscrtzdBCs = {c1fDirichBC, c1fNuemBC, c2fDirichBC, c2fNuemBC, 
    phiDirichBC, phiNuemBC} // ptoofunc;(*//MatrixForm*)
dscrtzdICs = 
  Map[removeredundant, 
   ptoofunc[{c1fIC, c2fIC, phiIC}]];(*///MatrixForm*)
dscrtzdGovEqns = 
  Map[removeredundant, 
   ptoofunc[{c1Trnsprt, c2Trnsprt, elctrcTrnsprt}]];(*//MatrixForm*)

(*Solving*)
sollst = 
  NDSolveValue[{dscrtzdBCs, dscrtzdICs, dscrtzdGovEqns}, 
   Outer[#[#2] &, {c1f, c2f, phi}, grid], {tStar, 0, 0.1}, 
   MaxSteps -> Infinity];
(*Rebuild the solution for the PDE from the solution for the ODE set:*)
sol = rebuild[sollst, grid];
```

However, I encountered the following issue despite I have equal number of discretized governing equations and discretized initial conditions.

> NDSolveValue::icfail: Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy
> the residual function within specified tolerances. Try giving initial
> conditions for both values and derivatives of the functions.

Code to check my number of discretized governing equations/discretized initial conditions/discretized boundary conditions:

```
Length@Flatten@dscrtzdGovEqns
Length@Flatten@dscrtzdICs
Length@Flatten@dscrtzdBCs
```

I am also curious to know if my system can be solved entirely just by using `NDSolve`, without the semi-manually-done spatial discretization.

Comment: Currently you're discretizing the system to a DAE system, which is harder to solve compared with ODE system. (Notice the `diffbc` function in the package, search in this site and you'll see example using it. ) But even if I improve the definition of `dscrtzdBCs` and `dscrtzdICs`, `NDSolve` is having difficulty with the system. According to my limited experience, this can be a sign of wrong equation or improper time interval. So, let me ask: 1. Are you sure the current end time i.e. `0.1` is proper? 2. Are you sure the equation system is correct?

Comment: @xzczd Actually, I am not sure of the end time. I am still estimating it now, thats why I simulate it from 0 to 0.01 seconds (which is equivalent to 0.1 in `tStar` domain, which is the scaled time). For a clearer context, I am computing the transport of salt ions (one PDE for c1f which is the co-ion, and one PDE for c2f which is the counter-ion) in a domain which consists of the solution (0<`xStar`<3) and the membrane (3<`xStar`<6). For completeness, I also consider poisson equation (the ODE) that governs the electrical charges caused by the salt ion and fixed charge group in the membrane.

Comment: Oh the domain is consist of different materials? Then that'll indeed be an issue. You need to avoid the automatic differentiation of the outer `D`, see e.g. the discussion [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/211314/1871).

Comment: One important thing to note is that, there is a steep change in mathematical solutions between the membrane and the contacting salt solution. I suspect this is one of the origins of the issue too.

Comment: @xzczd the domain consists of two different regimes (with different materials, so different transport properties). To tackle this, I am using a hyperbolic tangent function to simulate the jump in values of properties.

Currently, the only difference in the properties that i consider is the fixed charge, `cF[xStar]`. It exists in the membrane (3<`xStar`<6), but disappears in the contacting salt solution (0<`xStar`<3). This transition is approximated by a hyperbolic tangent function.

Comment: I know, using steep continuous function to approximate the jump is indeed valid approach, but more expensive. (you need to make the grid around the jump very dense. )

Comment: @xzczd I have tried modifying the grid such that it has denser grid points around the solution-membrane interface. Here is the new definition for `grid`:

xlist = {0};
xend = xlist[[Length[xlist]]];
coord = {{1}};
i = 1;
While[xend < xStarMemMid,
 i = i + 1;
 coord = Join[coord, {{i}}];
 xend = xend + d[xend];
 If[xend > xStarMemMid, xend = xStarMemMid;, xend = xend;];
 xlist = Insert[xlist, xend, (Length[xlist] + 1)];
 ]
grid = xlist;

Comment: @xzczd However, this method still does not work. Anyway, I still believe that a proper solution exists for my system because I managed to obtain the solution at `tStar`=0 and steady-state. I edited my post by adding more background explanation about my system, and demonstrated the solving code for `tStar`=0 and steady-state.

Comment: @xzczd I realized that I forgot to include the definition of `d[x]` for my edited `grid`. Here is the code for it:

`mshSze1 = 0.1;
mshSze2 = 0.05;
m = 5; (*Steepness*)
d[xStar_] = (mshSze1 - mshSze2 )/
     2*(Tanh[-m*(xStar - (xStarMem0 - 0.5))] + 
      1) + (mshSze1 - mshSze2 )/
     2*(Tanh[m*(xStar - (xStarMem0 + 0.5))] + 1) + 
   mshSze2;(*Without dip*)
Plot[d[x], {x, 0, xStarMemMid}, PlotRange -> {mshSze2, mshSze1}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Mesh Size VS xStar"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be solved with using implicit Euler for time step and linear FEM for space. This method described, for example, [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180959/solver-for-unsteady-flow-with-the-use-of-the-navier-stokes-and-mathematica-fem) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202446/solving-cahn-hilliard-equation-linearsolve-linear-equation-encountered-that-ha). First we transform equations to the system of ODEs and solve it with `NDSolve` as follows

```
(*Parameters*)kB = 1.380649*10^-23;
absTemp = 298.15;
beta = 1/(kB*absTemp);
eps0 = 8.8541878128*10^(-12);
eps = 78.6;
e = 1.60217663*10^(-19);
nA = 6.02214076*10^(23);
dfsvt = 1.33*10^(-9);
xRef = 10*10^(-6);
tRef = 10*10^(-2);
xStarMem0 = 3;
xStarMemMid = 6;
cSaltBar = 1500;(*mol/m3*)
cFVal = 300;(*mol/m3*)
cF[xStar_] = cFVal/2*(Tanh[15*(xStar - xStarMem0)] + 1);
z1 = -1;
z2 = 1;
deltaU = -1/beta;
vW = 30*10^(-30);
mu = 10^-2; nu = eps*eps0/(xRef^2*e*nA);
(*Governing Equations*)
c2b[xStar_, tStar_] = 
  cF[xStar]*(nA*c2f[xStar, tStar]*vW)/(nA*c2f[xStar, tStar]*vW + 
      Exp[beta*deltaU]);
c1Trnsprt = 
  D[c1f[xStar, tStar], tStar] == 
   tRef/(xRef^2)*
    D[dfsvt*(D[c1f[xStar, tStar], xStar] + 
        beta*z1*e*c1f[xStar, tStar]*D[phi[xStar, tStar], xStar]), 
     xStar];
c2Trnsprt = 
  D[c2f[xStar, tStar], tStar] == 
   tRef/(xRef^2)*
     D[dfsvt*(D[c2f[xStar, tStar], xStar] + 
         beta*z2*e*c2f[xStar, tStar]*D[phi[xStar, tStar], xStar]), 
      xStar] - D[c2b[xStar, tStar], tStar];
elctrcTrnsprt = 
  mu D[phi[xStar, tStar], tStar] == 
   D[D[phi[xStar, tStar], xStar], 
     xStar] + (-cF[xStar] + 
       z2*(c2f[xStar, tStar] + c2b[xStar, tStar]) + 
       z1*c1f[xStar, tStar])/nu;

(*Phi Solution for Initial Condition*)
(*IC Equations*)
c1fICsol[xStar_] = -z2/z1*
   cSaltBar/2*(Tanh[-15*(xStar - xStarMem0)] + 1);
c2fICsol[xStar_] = cSaltBar/2*(Tanh[-15*(xStar - xStarMem0)] + 1);
c2bICsol[xStar_] = 
  cF[xStar]*(nA*c2fICsol[xStar]*vW)/(nA*c2fICsol[xStar]*vW + 
      Exp[beta*deltaU]);
elctrcTrnsprtIC = 
  D[eps*eps0/(xRef^2*e*nA)*D[phiIC[xStar], xStar], 
    xStar] == -(-cF[xStar] + z2*(c2fICsol[xStar] + c2bICsol[xStar]) + 
       z1*c1fICsol[xStar]) + phiICNuemBC;
(*BCs*)
phiICDirichBC = phiIC[0] == 0;
phiICNuemBC = NeumannValue[0, xStar == xStarMemMid];
(*NDSolve*)
{phiSolIC} = 
  NDSolveValue[{elctrcTrnsprtIC, phiICDirichBC}, {phiIC}, {xStar, 0, 
    xStarMemMid}, 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
       "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 
          0.002}}}(*,{xStar}\[Element]xStarMesh*)];
(*Define the concentration function concentration[r,t]
phiSolIC[xStar_]=phiIC[xStar]/. totalSol[[1]];*)


 mesh = phiSolIC["ElementMesh"]

Out[]= ElementMesh[{{0., 6.}}, {LineElement["<" 3000 ">"]}]

 
C1F[0][x_] := -z2/z1*cSaltBar/2*(Tanh[-15*(x - xStarMem0)] + 1);
C2F[0][x_] := cSaltBar/2*(Tanh[-15*(x - xStarMem0)] + 1);
Phi[0][x_] := phiSolIC[x]; dt = 1/500;

AbsoluteTiming[Do[C2B = cF[x]*((nA*C2F[i - 1][x]*vW)/(nA*C2F[i - 1][x]*vW + Exp[beta*deltaU])); 
    {C1F[i], C2F[i], Phi[i]} = NDSolveValue[{(c1f[x] - C1F[i - 1][x])/dt == 
        (dfsvt*tRef*(beta*e*z1*Derivative[1][c1f][x]*Derivative[1][Phi[i - 1]][x] + Derivative[2][c1f][x] + 
           beta*e*z1*C1F[i - 1][x]*Derivative[2][phi][x]))/xRef^2, (cF[x]*((nA*c2f[x]*vW)/(nA*C2F[i - 1][x]*vW + Exp[beta*deltaU])) + c2f[x] - 
          C2B - C2F[i - 1][x])/dt == (dfsvt*tRef*(beta*e*z2*Derivative[1][c2f][x]*Derivative[1][Phi[i - 1]][x] + Derivative[2][c2f][x] + 
           beta*e*z2*C2F[i - 1][x]*Derivative[2][phi][x]))/xRef^2, (eps*eps0*Derivative[2][phi][x])/(e*nA*xRef^2) == 
        (-z1)*c1f[x] - z2*(cF[x]*((nA*c2f[x]*vW)/(nA*C2F[i - 1][x]*vW + Exp[beta*deltaU])) + c2f[x]) + cF[x], 
       DirichletCondition[{c1f[x] == (-z2/z1)*cSaltBar, c2f[x] == cSaltBar, phi[x] == 0}, x == 0]}, {c1f, c2f, phi}, Element[{x}, mesh]]; , 
   {i, 1, 50}]]
```

It takes about 38s on my laptop. Visualization

```
{Plot[Evaluate[Table[C1F[i][x], {i, 0, 50, 5}]], Element[{x}, mesh], 
  PlotLegends -> Table[Row[{"t =", N[i  dt]}], {i, 0, 50, 5}], 
  PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "c1f"}], 
 Plot[Evaluate[Table[C2F[i][x], {i, 0, 50, 5}]], Element[{x}, mesh], 
  PlotLegends -> Table[Row[{"t =", N[i  dt]}], {i, 0, 50, 5}], 
  PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "c2f"}]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Visualization at point `x=3.3`

```
{ListLinePlot[Table[{dt i, C1F[i][3.3]}, {i, 0, 50}], Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"t", "c1f"}, PlotRange -> All], 
 ListLinePlot[Table[{dt i, C2F[i][3.3]}, {i, 0, 50}], Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "c2f"}, PlotRange -> All], 
 ListLinePlot[Table[{dt i, Phi[i][3.3]}, {i, 1, 50}], Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"t", "phi"}, PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: Figure 2]

Electrical potential at different times (abs value)

```
LogPlot[Evaluate[Table[Abs[Phi[i][x]], {i, 0, 50, 5}]], {x, 0, 6}, 
 PlotRange -> Automatic, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "Phi"}, 
 PlotLegends -> Table[Row[{"t =", N[i  dt]}], {i, 0, 50, 5}]]
```

[image: Figure 3]

Comment: Thank you so much for the idea! I just checked the solution. However, it does not seem to match the trend of the steady-state solution that I provided in the post. I made a change to the mesh points. My code to create `mesh` is shown in the following:

Comment: `(*Mesh Points*)
mshSze1 = 0.05;
mshSze2 = 0.005;
m = 5; (*Steepness*)
(*d[xStar_]=(mshSze1-mshSze2 \
)/2*(Tanh[-m*(xStar-xStarMem0)]+1)+mshSze2;(*Without dip*)*)
d[xStar_] = (mshSze1 - mshSze2 )/
     2*(Tanh[-m*(xStar - (xStarMem0 - 0.5))] + 
      1) + (mshSze1 - mshSze2 )/
     2*(Tanh[m*(xStar - (xStarMem0 + 0.5))] + 1) + mshSze2;
Plot[d[x], {x, 0, xStarMemMid}, PlotRange -> {mshSze2, mshSze1}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Mesh Size VS xStar"]`

Comment: `xlist = {0};
xend = xlist[[Length[xlist]]];
coord = {{1}};
i = 1;
While[xend < xStarMemMid,
 i = i + 1;
 coord = Join[coord, {{i}}];
 xend = xend + d[xend];
 If[xend > xStarMemMid, xend = xStarMemMid;, xend = xend;];
 xlist = Insert[xlist, xend, (Length[xlist] + 1)];
 ]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[Map[{#} &, xlist]];`

Comment: With this change being made, I realized that the solution reaches steady state within the first few frames of the computation. As I further reduce `dt` ( sub-microsecond range, note that the actual time is `i*dt*tRef`, while the scaled time is `i*dt`), the solution begins to exhibit noticeable instabilities, before I am able to observe the detailed transient behavior.

Comment: This is implicit scheme on t only while linear FEM solver has own instabilities. In general there is optimal `dt` to solve this problem, since derivatives on `t` have singularities at $t\rightarrow 0$ due to jump in boundary conditions.

Comment: I just realized that there is a typo in your solution. In the second equation of the `NDSolve` command, `NDSolveValue[{...(cF[x]*((nA*c2f[x]*vW)/(nA*C2F[i - 1][x]*vW + Exp[beta*deltaU])) + c2f[x] - ...]` should change to `NDSolveValue[{...(cF[x]*((nA*c2f[x]*vW)/(nA*c2f[x]*vW + Exp[beta*deltaU])) + c2f[x] - ...]`. After imposing this correction and using a membrane-solution-interface-sensitive meshpoints (code is in the previous comment), I encountered this issue: FindRoot::dfmin: The minimal damping factor of 1/10000 has been reached.

Comment: @Johnson No it is not a typo. This is simplification to force `NDSolve`  to activate linear FEM, while with your correction  `NDSolve` uses nonlinear FEM.