# Strange behaviour in ToElementMesh

Tags: bugs, finite-element-method, mesh

**Bug introduced in version 12.1.1 or earlier, and persisting through 13.2.0 or later.**

---

Why would that not work:

```
L = 20;
h = 1;
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
gr = Graphics3D[Cuboid[{-h/2, 0, -h/2}, {h/2, L, h/2}]]
mesh = ToElementMesh[DiscretizeGraphics[gr], "MeshOrder" -> 1]
(* TetGenTetrahedrize: returned error, 2 *)
```

when with a simple translation of $(h/2, 0, h/2)$ I get no error?

```
gr = Graphics3D[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {h, L, h}]]
mesh = ToElementMesh[DiscretizeGraphics[gr], "MeshOrder" -> 1]
(* works *)
```

**Edit** Filled bug report `[CASE:4609730]`

Comment: You don't need `Graphics3D[...]` and `DiscretizeGraphics[...]`. Remove these and `mesh["Wireframe"]` works.

Comment: @flinty Ok but it is not a strange behaviour still, that only one works?

Comment: Maybe - there are all sorts of problems like this in the region functionality.

Comment: Seems a bug to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems something with the automatic `MaxCellMeasure` computation is not quite right. Here is a workaround with a manually specified `MaxCellMeasure`

```
mr = DiscretizeGraphics[gr];
(*ToElementMesh[mr]*)
ToElementMesh[mr, MaxCellMeasure -> .1]
```

**Update:**

This is a bug in TetGen, the mesh generator used.

```
(bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[mr]);
pts = bmesh["Coordinates"];
facets = Partition[
   Join @@ ElementIncidents[bmesh["BoundaryElements"]], 1];
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[pts, Map[Polygon, facets]]]
```

[image]

In the below code, if you change the 0.06 to 0.05, TetGen will fail.

```
Needs["TetGenLink`"]
inInst = TetGenCreate[];
TetGenSetPoints[inInst, pts];
TetGenSetFacets[inInst, facets];

(* changing "pqa0.006" to "pqa0.005" *)
outInst = TetGenTetrahedralize[inInst, "pqa0.006"];
coords = TetGenGetPoints[outInst];
surface = TetGenGetFaces[outInst];
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[coords, Polygon[surface]]]
```

[image]

Since TetGen is software that Wolfram Research purchased for inclusion there is little hope that this bug in TetGen will be fixed by myself or other people at Wolfram Research. Since the workaround is easy:

```
ToElementMesh[Cuboid[{-h/2, 0, -h/2}, {h/2, L, h/2}], 
 "MeshElementType" -> TetrahedronElement]
```

I do not think this is a critical bug. If you deeply care about this, you could try to make use of the TetGenLink that ships with Wolfram products and compile a newer version of TetGen and link and see if the bug has been fixed. Wolfram Products use TetGen version 1.4.3 and the current version is 1.5.1.

Comment: Nice suggestion to the user who didn't purchase TetGen but did purchase or receive his copy of Mathematica :( sorry for the sarcasm :(

Comment: @PavelPerikov, and what do you suggest I do?

Comment: you did great. Sorry if my comment sounded offensive in any way.

I think your explanation was delightful and useful.

Comment: @PavelPerikov, thanks for the clarification - I just wanted to be honest here, this is a bug and I should take care of it. At the same time I also want to be honest about my assessment of the difficulty/importance to fix this issue by saying that it is unlikely that I will fix this seen it is external code and not that critical. Now, I could be wrong. If enough people feel that this a vital thing to fix then the best way to proceed is to put it [on this list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/199163/18437) and I will try to make it happen.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the link!!!