# PDE system. convection dominated, method AffineCovariantNewton failed, etc

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, finite-element-method, nonlinear

I'm trying to solve numerically the following system in a rectangular region,

$\begin{align}
\cos\theta\frac{\partial\beta}{\partial x}+\sin\theta\frac{\partial\beta}{\partial y}&=\beta s\\-\sin\theta\frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial x}+\cos\theta\frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial y}&=-\alpha b\\\cos\theta\frac{\partial s}{\partial x}+\sin\theta\frac{\partial s}{\partial y}&=-s^{2}\\-\sin\theta\frac{\partial b}{\partial x}+\cos\theta\frac{\partial b}{\partial y}&=b^{2}\\
\cos\theta\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}+\sin\theta\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial y}&=b
\end{align}$

subject to initial conditions along an arbitrary line in the $x,y$ plane. To begin with I use the $x$ axis:

$\theta(x,0)=x^2, \frac{\partial\theta(x,0)}{\partial y}=x,\:s(x,0)=\cos x,\:\alpha(x,0)=\beta(x,0)=1,\:b(x,0)=\cos\theta(x,0)\frac{\partial\theta(x,0)}{\partial x}+\sin\theta(x,0)\frac{\partial\theta(x,0)}{\partial y}$

But mathematica is not returning anything, the solutions just satisfy the conditions and then drop to zero. I get the following warnings:

`NDSolve`FEM`InitializePDECoefficients::femcscd: The PDE is convection dominated and the result may not be stable. Adding artificial diffusion may help.`

`NDSolve`FEM`InitializePDECoefficients::femcscd: The PDE is convection dominated and the result may not be stable. Adding artificial diffusion may help.`

`FindRoot::stfail: The method AffineCovariantNewton failed to compute the next step.`

`FindRoot::sszero: The step size in the search has become less than the tolerance prescribed by the PrecisionGoal option, but the function value is still greater than the tolerance prescribed by the AccuracyGoal option.`

I don't have any clue what's the matter with NDSolve.

Thank you so much for any help.

The code:

```
region = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {0.5, 0.5}];
eq1 = Cos[θ[x, y]] D[β[x, y], x] + 
    Sin[θ[x, y]] D[β[x, y], y] == β[x, y] s[x, y];
eq2 = -Sin[θ[x, y]] D[α[x, y], x] + 
    Cos[θ[x, y]] D[α[x, y], y] == -α[x, y] b[x, 
     y];
eq3 = Cos[θ[x, y]] D[s[x, y], x] + 
    Sin[θ[x, y]] D[s[x, y], y] == -s[x, y]^2;
eq4 = -Sin[θ[x, y]] D[b[x, y], x] + 
    Cos[θ[x, y]] D[b[x, y], y] == b[x, y]^2;
eq5 = Cos[θ[x, y]] D[θ[x, y], x] + 
    Sin[θ[x, y]] D[θ[x, y], y] == b[x, y];
bc = {θ[x, 0] == x^2,
   β[x, 0] == 1,
   α[x, 0] == 1,
   s[x, 0] == Cos[x],
   b[x, 0] == 2 x Cos[x^2] + Sin[x^2] x};

sol = NDSolve[{{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5}, bc}, {α, β, b, 
    s, θ}, {x, y} ∈ region];
```

When plotting the solutions I get things like

[image]

Comment: The help has some information about this: have a look at FEMDocumentation/ref/message/InitializePDECoefficients/femcscd

Comment: The way you have posed your problem is that there is no driving force in the y-direction.  All your BCs are either constant or depend only on x. The y-derivatives in your equations should vanish.  A diffusive term or a flux boundary condition would drive some flow in the y-direction.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your remark. The BCs of course only depend on x because they are given along a y-constant line. Like in the wave equation, you specify the initial profile and velocity at t=0, the BCs doesn't depend on t.

Comment: If you are replying to me, you need to start with the@TimLaska so that I am notified of your reply. The wave equation has a second-order time derivative plus a second-order spatial derivative (a diffusive or Laplacian term). You only have first-order spatial or convective terms.

Comment: @TimLaska sorry about that, I just forgot it. Yes, but actually my systems of equations is a first order one because I split it that way. If you eliminate b and s you get second order equations for \theta. This system is a hyperbolic system of PDEs, which means that its BCs are similar to those satisfied by the wave equation, despite the fact that it looks quite different.

Comment: Version 13 has [ToGradedMesh](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToGradedMesh.html) and [ElementMeshRegionProduct](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ElementMeshRegionProduct.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an extended comment versus an answer. Following @user21's link, it suggests refining the mesh at the boundaries. The features are very sharp at the Y = 0 boundary. I am going to apply anisotropic meshing and attempt to capture the features. Furthermore, I'm going to shrink the y-dimension since the solution falls off very quickly.

## Helper functions

To create the anisotropic mesh, I will first find some helper functions:

```
(*Import required FEM package*)
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
(* Define Some Helper Functions For Structured Quad Mesh*)
pointsToMesh[data_] :=
  MeshRegion[Transpose[{data}], 
   Line@Table[{i, i + 1}, {i, Length[data] - 1}]];
unitMeshGrowth[n_, r_] := 
 Table[(r^(j/(-1 + n)) - 1.)/(r - 1.), {j, 0, n - 1}]
meshGrowth[x0_, xf_, n_, r_] := (xf - x0) unitMeshGrowth[n, r] + x0
firstElmHeight[x0_, xf_, n_, r_] := 
 Abs@First@Differences@meshGrowth[x0, xf, n, r]
lastElmHeight[x0_, xf_, n_, r_] := 
 Abs@Last@Differences@meshGrowth[x0, xf, n, r]
findGrowthRate[x0_, xf_, n_, fElm_] := 
 Quiet@Abs@
   FindRoot[firstElmHeight[x0, xf, n, r] - fElm, {r, 1.0001, 100000}, 
     Method -> "Brent"][[1, 2]]
meshGrowthByElm[x0_, xf_, n_, fElm_] := 
 N@Sort@Chop@meshGrowth[x0, xf, n, findGrowthRate[x0, xf, n, fElm]]
meshGrowthByElm0[len_, n_, fElm_] := meshGrowthByElm[0, len, n, fElm]
flipSegment[l_] := (#1 - #2) & @@ {First[#], #} &@Reverse[l];
leftSegmentGrowth[len_, n_, fElm_] := meshGrowthByElm0[len, n, fElm]
rightSegmentGrowth[len_, n_, fElm_] := Module[{seg},
  seg = leftSegmentGrowth[len, n, fElm];
  flipSegment[seg]
  ]
reflectRight[pts_] := With[{rt = ReflectionTransform[{1}, {Last@pts}]},
  Union[pts, Flatten[rt /@ Partition[pts, 1]]]]
reflectLeft[pts_] := 
 With[{rt = ReflectionTransform[{-1}, {First@pts}]},
  Union[pts, Flatten[rt /@ Partition[pts, 1]]]]
extendMesh[mesh_, newmesh_] := Union[mesh, Max@mesh + newmesh]
```

## Create an isotropic Quad mesh

I'm going to shrink the y-dimension to ${10^{ - 7}}$ and have a growth rate where the first element is a thousand times smaller than the last element.

```
seg = Subdivide[0, 0.5, 40];
Print["Horizontal segment"]
rh = pointsToMesh@seg
seg = leftSegmentGrowth[0.0000001, 100, 0.0000001/1000];
Print["Vertical segment"]
rv = pointsToMesh@seg
(*View Region Product of horiz and vert segs*)
Print["2D Region via RegionProduct"]
rp = RegionProduct[rh, rv]
(*Extract Coords from RegionProduct*)
crd = MeshCoordinates[rp];
(*grab quad element incidents RegionProduct mesh*)
inc = Delete[0] /@ MeshCells[rp, 2];
(mesh = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> crd, 
    "MeshElements" -> {QuadElement[inc]}])["Wireframe"]
```

[image: Then 2D mesh]

## Solve and plot the solutions

```
eq1 = Cos[θ[x, y]] D[β[x, y], x] + 
    Sin[θ[x, y]] D[β[x, y], y] == β[x, y] s[x, y];
eq2 = -Sin[θ[x, y]] D[α[x, y], x] + 
    Cos[θ[x, y]] D[α[x, y], y] == -α[x, y] b[x, 
     y];
eq3 = Cos[θ[x, y]] D[s[x, y], x] + 
    Sin[θ[x, y]] D[s[x, y], y] == -s[x, y]^2;
eq4 = -Sin[θ[x, y]] D[b[x, y], x] + 
    Cos[θ[x, y]] D[b[x, y], y] == b[x, y]^2;
eq5 = Cos[θ[x, y]] D[θ[x, y], x] + 
    Sin[θ[x, y]] D[θ[x, y], y] == b[x, y];
bc = {θ[x, 0] == x^2, β[x, 0] == 1, α[x, 0] == 1, 
   s[x, 0] == Cos[x], b[x, 0] == 2 x Cos[x^2] + Sin[x^2] x};
{αfun, βfun, bfun, sfun, θfun} = 
  NDSolveValue[{{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5}, bc}, {α, β, b,
     s, θ}, {x, y} ∈ mesh];
{αfun, βfun, bfun, sfun, θfun} = 
  NDSolveValue[{{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5}, bc}, {α, β, b,
     s, θ}, {x, y} ∈ mesh];
Plot3D[αfun[x, y], {x, y} ∈ mesh, PlotPoints -> All, 
 ViewPoint -> Right]
Plot3D[βfun[x, y], {x, y} ∈ mesh, PlotPoints -> All, 
 ViewPoint -> Right]
Plot3D[bfun[x, y], {x, y} ∈ mesh, PlotPoints -> All, 
 ViewPoint -> Right]
Plot3D[sfun[x, y], {x, y} ∈ mesh, PlotPoints -> All, 
 ViewPoint -> Right]
Plot3D[θfun[x, y], {x, y} ∈ mesh, PlotPoints -> All, 
 ViewPoint -> Right]
```

[image: No diffusive term solution]

As you can see, nothing gets pulled off the Y = 0 boundary, even at incredible resolution.

## Add a diffusive term to the full domain

```
seg = Subdivide[0, 0.5, 40];
Print["Horizontal segment"]
rh = pointsToMesh@seg
seg = leftSegmentGrowth[0.5, 100, 0.5/1000];
Print["Vertical segment"]
rv = pointsToMesh@seg
(*View Region Product of horiz and vert segs*)
Print["2D Region via RegionProduct"]
rp = RegionProduct[rh, rv]
(*Extract Coords from RegionProduct*)
crd = MeshCoordinates[rp];
(*grab quad element incidents RegionProduct mesh*)
inc = Delete[0] /@ MeshCells[rp, 2];
Print["Element mesh"]
(mesh = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> crd, 
    "MeshElements" -> {QuadElement[inc]}])["Wireframe"]
(*Artificial diffusion constant*)
cart = 10^-3
eq1 = Cos[θ[x, y]] D[β[x, y], x] + 
    Sin[θ[x, y]] D[β[x, y], y] + 
    Div[-cart Grad[β[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] == β[x, y] s[
     x, y];
eq2 = -Sin[θ[x, y]] D[α[x, y], x] + 
    Cos[θ[x, y]] D[α[x, y], y] + 
    Div[-cart Grad[α[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] == -α[x, 
      y] b[x, y];
eq3 = Cos[θ[x, y]] D[s[x, y], x] + 
    Sin[θ[x, y]] D[s[x, y], y] + 
    Div[-cart Grad[s[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] == -s[x, y]^2;
eq4 = -Sin[θ[x, y]] D[b[x, y], x] + 
    Cos[θ[x, y]] D[b[x, y], y] + 
    Div[-cart Grad[b[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] == b[x, y]^2;
eq5 = Cos[θ[x, y]] D[θ[x, y], x] + 
    Sin[θ[x, y]] D[θ[x, y], y] + 
    Div[-cart Grad[θ[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] == b[x, y];
bc = {θ[x, 0] == x^2, β[x, 0] == 1, α[x, 0] == 1, 
   s[x, 0] == Cos[x], b[x, 0] == 2 x Cos[x^2] + Sin[x^2] x};
{αfun, βfun, bfun, sfun, θfun} = 
  NDSolveValue[{{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5}, bc}, {α, β, b,
     s, θ}, {x, y} ∈ mesh];
{αfun, βfun, bfun, sfun, θfun} = 
  NDSolveValue[{{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5}, bc}, {α, β, b,
     s, θ}, {x, y} ∈ mesh];
Print["Plot of solutions"]
Plot3D[αfun[x, y], {x, y} ∈ mesh, PlotPoints -> All, 
 PlotRange -> All, ViewPoint -> Right]
Plot3D[βfun[x, y], {x, y} ∈ mesh, PlotPoints -> All, 
 PlotRange -> All, ViewPoint -> Right]
Plot3D[bfun[x, y], {x, y} ∈ mesh, PlotPoints -> All, 
 PlotRange -> All, ViewPoint -> Right]
Plot3D[sfun[x, y], {x, y} ∈ mesh, PlotPoints -> All, 
 PlotRange -> All, ViewPoint -> Right]
Plot3D[θfun[x, y], {x, y} ∈ mesh, PlotPoints -> All, 
 PlotRange -> All, ViewPoint -> Right]
```

[image: Solutions with artificial diffusion]

As you can see, an explicit diffusive term will pull material into the domain from the boundary.

Comment: @Daniel Castro, Tim made a proposal to add anisotropic meshing capabilities to the FEM mesh generation [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/240408/18437). If you think this is worthwhile, consider giving this proposal an upvote

Answer (score 5):

This is the same approach that Tim describes in his solution, but implemented with the [ToGradedMesh](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToGradedMesh.html) and [ElementMeshRegionProduct](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ElementMeshRegionProduct.html) functions added in version 13.0:

```
meshX = ToGradedMesh[Line[{{0}, {0.5}}], <|"ElementCount" -> 40|>];
meshY = ToGradedMesh[Line[{{0}, {0.5}}],
    <|"Alignment" -> "Left",
    "ElementCount" -> 100, 
    "MinimalDistance" -> 0.5/1000|>
];

MeshRegion /@ {meshX, meshY}
```

[image: meshXY]

```
mesh = ElementMeshRegionProduct[meshX, meshY];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image: mesh]

```
cart = 10^-3;
eq1 = Cos[θ[x, y]] D[β[x, y], x] + 
    Sin[θ[x, y]] D[β[x, y], y] + 
    Div[-cart Grad[β[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] == β[x, y] s[
     x, y];
eq2 = -Sin[θ[x, y]] D[α[x, y], x] + 
    Cos[θ[x, y]] D[α[x, y], y] + 
    Div[-cart Grad[α[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] == -α[x, 
      y] b[x, y];
eq3 = Cos[θ[x, y]] D[s[x, y], x] + 
    Sin[θ[x, y]] D[s[x, y], y] + 
    Div[-cart Grad[s[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] == -s[x, y]^2;
eq4 = -Sin[θ[x, y]] D[b[x, y], x] + 
    Cos[θ[x, y]] D[b[x, y], y] + 
    Div[-cart Grad[b[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] == b[x, y]^2;
eq5 = Cos[θ[x, y]] D[θ[x, y], x] + 
    Sin[θ[x, y]] D[θ[x, y], y] + 
    Div[-cart Grad[θ[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] == b[x, y];
bc = {θ[x, 0] == x^2, β[x, 0] == 1, α[x, 0] == 1, 
   s[x, 0] == Cos[x], b[x, 0] == 2 x Cos[x^2] + Sin[x^2] x};
{αfun, βfun, bfun, sfun, θfun} = 
  NDSolveValue[{{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5}, bc}, {α, β, b,
     s, θ}, {x, y} ∈ mesh];
{αfun, βfun, bfun, sfun, θfun} = 
  NDSolveValue[{{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5}, bc}, {α, β, b,
     s, θ}, {x, y} ∈ mesh];
Print["Plot of solutions"]
Plot3D[αfun[x, y], {x, y} ∈ mesh, PlotPoints -> All, 
 PlotRange -> All, ViewPoint -> Right]
Plot3D[βfun[x, y], {x, y} ∈ mesh, PlotPoints -> All, 
 PlotRange -> All, ViewPoint -> Right]
Plot3D[bfun[x, y], {x, y} ∈ mesh, PlotPoints -> All, 
 PlotRange -> All, ViewPoint -> Right]
Plot3D[sfun[x, y], {x, y} ∈ mesh, PlotPoints -> All, 
 PlotRange -> All, ViewPoint -> Right]
Plot3D[θfun[x, y], {x, y} ∈ mesh, PlotPoints -> All, 
 PlotRange -> All, ViewPoint -> Right]
```

[image: solutions]