# How to add an attractive potential (migration term) named component to Mass Transport PDE

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, physics, modeling, mass-transport

Wolfram Mathematica 12.2 now features [*"Named Partial Differential Equation Terms"*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/PDEModeling.html)

> For specific physics fields, relevant PDE terms have been packaged as
> components and augmented with boundary condition functions typically
> encountered in the field.

I'm interested in [Mass Transport PDEs and Boundary Conditions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/MassTransportPDEModels.html) and particularly on how to introduce a migration term, *i.e* a physical potential or force terms to a diffusion problem. This is to model the time evolution of the probability to find diffusing particles experiencing forces in solution.

An example PDE without potentials is

```
With[
 {
  length = 500,
  height = 30
  },
 Ω = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {length, height}]; (* Domain *)
 pars = <| (* Parameters *)
   "DiffusionCoefficient" -> 10,
   Vavg -> 10,
   "MassConvectionVelocity" -> {2 Vavg*(1 - ((y - height/2)/(height/2))^2), 0},
   "Method" -> "StiffnessSwitching"
   |>;
 vars = {c[t, x, y], t, {x, y}}; (* Variables *)
 Gin = MassConcentrationCondition[x == 0, vars, pars, <|"MassConcentration" -> 0|>];
 Gbottom = 
  MassFluxValue[
  y == 0,
  vars, 
  pars,
  <|"MassFlux" -> 2 UnitBox[(x - 100)/50] Exp[-(1/2) (t - 2)^2], 
    "BoundaryUnitNormal" -> {0, 1}|>];
 Gtop = MassImpermeableBoundaryValue[y == height, vars, pars, <|"BoundaryUnitNormal" -> {0, -1}|>];
 ics = { c[0, x, y] == 0};
 pde = {
   MassTransportPDEComponent[vars, pars] == Gtop + Gbottom
   , Gin
   , ics
   };
 ]
```

With solution

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[
  cfun = NDSolveValue[
     pde
     , c
     , {t, 0, 20}
     , {x, y} ∈ Ω
     , InterpolationOrder -> 2
     , AccuracyGoal -> 14
     , Method -> Automatic
     , MaxStepFraction -> 1/6000
     ];
  ]
```

[image]

**How do I add an attractive potential using the packaged named terms?**

For the interested reader, think Smoluchowski or Fokker-Planck equations as described in chapter 4 [here](https://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Services/Class/NSM.pdf).

Comment: Hi, is the answer I posted in any way useful?

Comment: Thank to @user21 and TimLaska for the answers. I'm splitting my time in two different tasks and I haven't fully digested them yet. Please give some a couple of days to implement and compare your answers. I will comment or/and accept then. Cheers!

Comment: Pining again to check if any of this is useful?

Comment: There is an example of the [Fokker-Plank equation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MassTransportPDEComponent.html#1981924737) and the [Smoluchowski diffusion equation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MassTransportPDEComponent.html#973842730) in the documentation of version 12.3. Hope that is useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am anything else than an expert in statistics and I can not directly answer your question. However, I can show how I modeled a Fokker-Planck equation in the hope that this helps you move forward. I Have grabbed the [first PDF](http://congress.cimne.com/eccomas/proceedings/compdyn2011/compdyn2011_full/059.pdf) that a search for FEM + Fokker-Planck gave me and I am going to show how to replicate that example.

Before I do that, I'd like to point you to an undocumented function that shows the string parameter names a specific PDE component responds to:

```
PDEModels`PDEModelParameters[MassTransportPDEComponent]

{"DiffusionCoefficient", "MassConvectionVelocity", \
"MassReactionRate", "MassSource", "ModelForm"}
```

Next, I'd like to model equation 7 from the mentioned paper, which is a Fokker-Planck equation. To do so, I myself go in steps. I start with a default setup.

```
vars = {c[t, x, y], t, {x, y}};
pars = <||>;
MassTransportPDEComponent[vars, pars]

Inactive[Div][{{-1, 0}, {0, -1}} . Inactive[Grad][c[t, x, y], {x, y}], 
  {x, y}] + Derivative[1, 0, 0][c][t, x, y]
```

First, I set the diffusion coefficient such that it corresponds to the one one in the paper. This is symbolic for now.

```
pars["DiffusionCoefficient"] = {{0, 0}, {0, D}};
MassTransportPDEComponent[vars, pars]

Inactive[Div][{{0, 0}, {0, -D}} . Inactive[Grad][c[t, x, y], {x, y}], 
  {x, y}] + Derivative[1, 0, 0][c][t, x, y]
```

Next is the conservative convection part. Conservative vs. non-conservative is explained in the [ref page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MassTransportPDEComponent.html#1091028538) or in the [MassTransport tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/MassTransport/MassTransport.html#101534413)

```
pars["ModelForm"] = "Conservative";
pars["MassConvectionVelocity"] = {y, -2 \[Xi] \[Omega] y - x};
MassTransportPDEComponent[vars, pars]

Inactive[Div][{{0, 0}, {0, -D}} . Inactive[Grad][c[t, x, y], {x, y}], 
  {x, y}] + Inactive[Div][{y*c[t, x, y], (-x - 2*y*\[Xi]*\[Omega])*c[t, x, y]}, 
  {x, y}] + Derivative[1, 0, 0][c][t, x, y]
```

To cross check this I used:

```
temp = MassTransportPDEComponent[{p[t, x, y], {x, y}}, pars];
(-temp) // Activate // Simplify
```

This should be equivalent to equation 8 from the paper.

Now, we set up the parameters.

```
rules = {\[Mu] -> {5, 5}, \[Sigma] -> 1/9*IdentityMatrix[2], \[Xi] -> 
   1/20, \[Omega] -> 1, D -> 1/10}
```

We could very well also put these in `pars`.

The initial condition:

```
ics = c[0, x, y] == 
  PDF[MultinormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]] /. rules, {x, y}]
```

The boundary condition:

```
G1 = NeumannValue[0, True]
```

(we do not really need this)

Domain and time:

```
\[CapitalOmega] = Rectangle[{-10, -10}, {10, 10}];
tEnd = 100;
```

According to the paper, a first order mesh is OK:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.05, 
   "MeshOrder" -> 1];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Now we solve the equation, note that this can be memory consuming, also mentioned in the paper.

```
op = MassTransportPDEComponent[vars, pars];
if = Monitor[
  NDSolveValue[{op == G1, ics} /. rules, 
   c, {t, 0, tEnd}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
   EvaluationMonitor :> (monitor = Row[{"t = ", CForm[t]}])], monitor]
```

Visualize:

```
Plot[if[t, 0, 0], {t, 0, tEnd}, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, Range[0, 0.18, 0.02]}, 
 GridLines -> {Automatic, Range[0, 0.18, 0.02]}]
```

[image]

which replicates figure 1 from the paper.

```
frames = ContourPlot[if[#, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
     PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
     Contours -> Range[0.05, 2, 0.05]] & /@ Range[0, tEnd, 1];

ListAnimate[frames]
```

[image]

**Update**

The explicit example you requested can be done along the same procedure from above.

```
vars = {p[t, x], t, {x}};
pars = <||>;
pars["DiffusionCoefficient"] = {{D}};
pars["ModelForm"] = "Conservative";
(* Eqn 4.17 ff *)
potential[x_] := c x
pars["MassConvectionVelocity"] = \[Beta] *(-Grad[potential[x], {x}]);
MassTransportPDEComponent[vars, pars]

Inactive[Div][{{-D}} . Inactive[Grad][p[t, x], {x}], {x}] + 
 Inactive[Div][{-(c*\[Beta]*p[t, x])}, {x}] + Derivative[1, 0][p][t, x]
```

Set up some parameters, the region and the analytical solution:

```
\[CapitalOmega] = Line[{{-s}, {s}}] /. s -> 8;
rules = {D -> 1, \[Beta] -> 1, c -> 1};
anaSol[t_, x_] := Evaluate[With[{x0 = 0, t0 = 0},
    1/Sqrt[4 \[Pi] D (t - t0)]*
     Exp[-(x - x0 + D \[Beta] c (t - t0))^2 / (4 D *(t - t0))]] /. 
   rules]
```

Generate the initial conditions:

```
tStart = 1/10;
ics = p[tStart, x] == anaSol[tStart, x];
```

Solve the PDE:

```
op = MassTransportPDEComponent[vars, pars] /. rules;
tEnd = 1;
if = NDSolveValue[{op == 0, ics}, 
  p, {t, tStart, tEnd}, {x} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]]
```

Visualize:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{anaSol[t, x], if[t, x]}, {x} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
  PlotRange -> All], {t, tStart, tEnd}]
```

Error:

```
Plot[{anaSol[tEnd, x] - if[tEnd, x]}, {x} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @user21, I'm trying your answer now, but as a preliminary comment, you chose to work on a different example than mine, and don't mention explicitly which terms play the role of forces or potentials, which is the core of my question. I hate to move the goalpost, but it would be nice to have an answer that can be contrasted with an analytical solution, like eqn 4.39 in [here](https://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Services/Class/NSM.pdf)

Comment: @rhermans, see update, same procedure. I think what you might have missed is the -Grad[U[X],{x}] == F[X]

Answer (score 6):

From my reading of the documentation for the [`MassTransportPDEComponent`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MassTransportPDEComponent.html), it appears to be currently missing the ability to add a migration term. Consider, for example, the *Nernst-Planck* equation:

$$\frac{{\partial {c_i}}}{{\partial t}} + \nabla \cdot\underbrace {\left( { - {D_{AB}}\nabla {c_i} - {c_i}{\bf{u}} + {z_i}{u_i}{c_i}E} \right)}_{{{\bf{N}}_i}} - {R_i} = 0$$

Where

$${{\bf{N}}_i} =  - \overbrace {{D_i}\nabla {c_i}}^{Diff} - \overbrace {{c_i}{\bf{u}}}^{Conv} + \overbrace {{z_i}{u_i}{c_i}E}^{Migr}$$

It is not difficult to add a migration term through the use of the PDE building block [`DerivativePDETerm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DerivativePDETerm.html). In coefficient form, the PDE may be expressed as:

$$m\frac{{{\partial ^2}}}{{\partial {t^2}}}u + d\frac{\partial }{{\partial t}}u + \nabla \cdot\left( { - c\nabla u - \alpha u + \gamma } \right) + \beta \cdot\nabla u + au - f = 0$$

Therefore, $\gamma=Migration=DerivativePDETerm$. Here is an example how we can add it to the pde:

```
With[{length = 500, height = 30}, Ω = 
  Rectangle[{0, 0}, {length, height}];(*Domain*)
 pars = <|(*Parameters*)"DiffusionCoefficient" -> 10, Vavg -> 10, 
   "MassConvectionVelocity" -> {2 Vavg*(1 - ((y - height/2)/(height/
             2))^2), 0}, "Method" -> "StiffnessSwitching"|>;
 vars = {c[t, x, y], t, {x, y}};(*Variables*)
 Gin = MassConcentrationCondition[x == 0, vars, 
   pars, <|"MassConcentration" -> 0|>];
 Gbottom = 
  MassFluxValue[y == 0, vars, 
   pars, <|"MassFlux" -> 
     2 UnitBox[(x - 100)/50] Exp[-(1/2) (t - 2)^2], 
    "BoundaryUnitNormal" -> {0, 1}|>];
 Gtop = MassImpermeableBoundaryValue[y == height, vars, 
   pars, <|"BoundaryUnitNormal" -> {0, -1}|>];
 ics = {c[0, x, y] == 0};
 pde = {MassTransportPDEComponent[vars, pars] + 
     DerivativePDETerm[vars, {- 8 c[t, x, y], c[t, x, y]}] == 
    Gtop + Gbottom, Gin, ics};]
```

Now, we can set up and solve the system and observe that it is different from the original solution.

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[
  cfun = NDSolveValue[pde, 
     c, {t, 0, 20}, {x, y} ∈ Ω, 
     InterpolationOrder -> 2, AccuracyGoal -> 14, Method -> Automatic,
      MaxStepFraction -> 1/6000];]
DensityPlot[cfun[20, x, y], {x, y} ∈ Ω, 
 ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image: Force field modified]

Original solution:

[image: Original solution]

There could be implications for how this term interacts with boundary conditions. You may want to request a migration term be added to the MassTransportPDEComponent to the [Future enhancements for the finite element method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/199163/61809) page to ensure that it gets handled properly.

Comment: Thanks! Can you elaborate on the boundary conditions it may affect so I can dig on how to tackle that problem? As suggested, I have added an entry to *"Future enhancements for the finite element method
"* in [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/241678/10397). Cheers!

Comment: @rhermans If you look at the [Partial Differential Equations and Boundary Conditions](https://wolfram.com/xid/0l2dr3m3kowkmft2kv6cvtalu635w4q6ys-madjm0) section in the `Solving Partial Differential Equations with Finite Elements`, they talk about a generalized Neumann boundary value also known as a Robin value. It takes the form of $\mathord{\buildrel{\lower3pt\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\rightharpoonup$}} 
\over n} \cdot\left( {c\nabla u + \alpha u - \gamma } \right) = \left( {g - qu} \right)$ that contains $\gamma$. It seems there is a potential to interact with Robin values.

Comment: Thanks Tim. If a migration term is `z u c E` and `c` is the dependent variable, could one not put this in the conservative convection coefficient alpha?

Comment: @user21 Yes, it appears you could do that in the _Nernst Planck_ case and it may be a solution to many other cases of interest. I initially tried that approach and ran into some problems. Perhaps I need to revisit. Unfortunately, my experience in this class of physics (i.e., adding a force field) is very limited so I do not have a good feel for what the types of terms are and what good solutions look like.

Comment: @TimLaska, same problem here, lack of experience, that's why there is no example of this type. We will see where this question leads too.