# Fokker Planck Equation in Mathematica giving weird solution

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, finite-element-method

I have the following equation $$\frac{\partial\,P(\theta,t)}{\partial t} = \alpha\cos\theta\,P(\theta,t) + \beta \frac{\partial^2\,P(\theta,t)}{\partial \theta^2} $$
subject to following conditions$$P(\theta, 0)=\delta(\theta-\pi/4), P(\theta,t)=P(\theta+2\pi,t)~.$$

I tried solving this numerically in Mathematica:

```
alpha = 0.02
beta = 0.02
fokkerPlanck = {D[p[x, t], t]==alpha*Cos[x]*p[x,t] + beta*D[p[x,t],{x,2}], p[x,0] == DiracDelta[Pi/4], p[2Pi, t] == p[0, t]};
sol = Flatten@NDSolve[fokkerPlanck, p, {x, 0, 2Pi},{t, 0, 100}]
```

If I run this, I get null solution, so something is weird. Could anyone let me know what is potentially wrong here?

Comment: From the first glance, you need to fix also the interval in x and the corresponding boundary conditions. Am I wrong?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch You are right that I need to add interval in x. I was doing that in my code, but while typing it here, I missed it. This is now fixed. The boundary conditions are already included in fokkerPlanck though.

Comment: There is an [example Fokker-Panck equation in the reference](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MassTransportPDEComponent.html#1981924737). Maybe that's useful. See also [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/241642/18437)

Comment: @titanium Initial condition is not periodic, while boundary condition is periodic. What kind of solution do you expect?

Answer (score 2):

It seems the problem is the the `DiracDelta` boundary condition.

If I replace that with a highly peaked Gaussian, `p[x, 0] == Exp[-(x - \[Pi]/4)^2/(2*0.001)^2]`, I get a finite solution.

Comment: Even if I do so, plot of p[x, 100] looks really weird; its amplitude is way too small.

Comment: Well it's a diffusion equation, the width is supposed to get larger. Also your equation does not have a $P$ on the $\alpha$ term, but your Mathematica code does?

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I corrected the problem. My point was after running the code for long enough, the distribution of p[x,100] should be a Gaussian distribution which integrates to 1 in the range of 0, 2Pi. This is because p is the probability density. At the moment I cannot recover this.

Comment: @titanium Gaussian distribution defined on $-\infty <x<\infty$. It is not periodic function on $0\le x\le 2 \pi$

Answer (score 1):

First step is come out from singularity at $t=0$. For this we can use analytical solution in the form

```
sol1 = 
 DSolve[{D[p[x, t], t] == 
    1/50*Cos[x]*p[x, t] + 1/50*D[p[x, t], {x, 2}], 
   p[x, 0] == DiracDelta[(x - Pi/4)]}, p[x, t], {x, t}]

Out[]= {{p[x, t] -> 
   ConditionalExpression[(
    5 E^(-((25 (\[Pi] - 4 x)^2)/(32 t)) + 1/50 t Cos[x]))/(
    Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] Sqrt[t]), Re[t] > 0]}}
```

This solution is not periodic on $0\le x \le 2 \pi$, but we can make it periodic for $t>t_0$ using FEM as follows

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
alpha = 0.02;
beta = 0.02; reg = Rectangle[{0, 1/2}, {2 Pi, 100}]; mesh = 
 ToElementMesh[reg, 
  MeshRefinementFunction -> 
   Function[{vertices, area}, 
    area > 0.001 (0.05 + 3 Norm[Mean[vertices]])]]
fokkerPlanck = {D[p[x, t], t] == 
    alpha*Cos[x]*p[x, t] + beta*D[p[x, t], {x, 2}], 
   DirichletCondition[
    p[x, t] == (
     5 E^(-((25 (\[Pi] - 4 x)^2)/(32 t)) + 1/50 t Cos[x]))/(
     Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] Sqrt[t]), t == 1/2 && 10^-2 <= x <= 2 Pi - 10^-2], 
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[p[x, t], x == 2 \[Pi], 
    Function[x, x - 2 \[Pi]]]};

sol = NDSolve[fokkerPlanck, p, Element[{x, t}, mesh]]
```

There is a message about stability of solution

```
NDSolve::femcscd: The PDE is convection dominated and the result may not be stable. Adding artificial diffusion may help.
```

Visualization
[image: Figure 1]

Comment: If I execute the `DSolve` part for obtaining analytical solution, it returns me the code I entered, not the analytical result. Any idea on why that might be the case? I cleared all the cache as well, but that did not help.

Comment: @titanium What version do you run?

Comment: It is version 12.0.0.0.

Comment: @titanium Ok! My `$Version` is  `12.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (May 10, 2021)`. But `DSolve` has been updated in 12. Could you show code you execute?