# Solve 1d fractional equation with Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, boundary-conditions

How can we use Mathematica to solve the following fractional elliptic problem?
$$a(-\Delta)^su + bu= f(x) \text{ in } (0,1),\\
u = c \text{ in } \mathbb{R} \setminus (0,1), $$
for $a,b,c\ge0$ and a smooth function f.
Here $(-\Delta)^s$ is the [singular integral fractional Laplacian](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/mediawiki/index.php/Fractional_Laplacian?#As_a_singular_integral).

There is a related question [Implement fractional Laplacian](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/156420/implement-fractional-laplacian) but it refers to a less general problem (a=1, b=0, $f\equiv 1$, c = 0) and uses a spectral definition of the fractional Laplacian.

Comment: There is FDM algorithm described in the paper on https://epubs.siam.org/doi/epdf/10.1137/140954040

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem can be solved with using colocation method and Euler wavelets. We define fractional Laplacian as in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.7691) in the form

```
c[n_, a_] := a 2^(a - 1) Gamma[(a + n)/2]/(Pi^(n/2) Gamma[1 - a/2]);
lap[n_, a_, x_, u_] := 
  c[n, a] Integrate[(u[x] - u[y])/Abs[x - y]^(n + a), y];
```

with $0 < a < 2$. Let consider equation

$$d (-\Delta)^\frac{a}{2}u(x)+b u(x)=f(x)$$ for $0<x<1$, and boundary conditions
$$u=u_c(x), x\le0||x\ge 1$$
Our method is based on wavelets definition

```
UE[m_, t_] := EulerE[m, t]
psi[k_, n_, m_, t_] := 
 Piecewise[{{2^(k/2) Sqrt[2/Pi] UE[m, 2^k t - 2 n + 1], (n - 1)/
      2^(k - 1) <= t < n/2^(k - 1)}, {0, True}}]
PsiE[k_, M_, t_] := 
 Flatten[Table[psi[k, n, m, t], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]
k0 = 3; M0 = 4; nn = 
 Total[With[{k = k0, M = M0}, 
   Flatten[Table[1, {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]]]; dx = 
 1/(nn);  xl = Table[ l*dx, {l, 0, nn}]; tcol = 
 Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, nn + 1}]; Psijk = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, PsiE[k, M, t1]]; Psi[y_] := Psijk /. t1 -> y;
```

It means that in this particular case we use nn=16 colocation point. To compute numerical matrix for the fractional Laplacian we need first define parameters `s=a, d, b` and functions `uc, f`, for example,

```
s = 1/2;d=1;b=1; ue[a_, x_] := (1 + x^2)^(-(1 - a)/2);uc[x_] := ue[s, x];
lape[a_, x_] := 
  2^a Gamma[(1 + a)/2]/Gamma[(1 - a)/2] (1 + x^2)^(-(1 + a)/2); 
f[x_] := d lape[s, x] + b ue[s, x];
```

Then we compute

```
int = 
 Table[Table[
   NIntegrate[(Psi[tcol[[i]]][[j]] - 
       Psi[y][[j]])/(tcol[[i]] - y)^(1 + s), {y, 0, tcol[[i]]}, 
    Method -> "PrincipalValue", Exclusions -> tcol[[i]] - y == 0, 
    AccuracyGoal -> 6, PrecisionGoal -> 6], {j, nn}], {i, nn}];

int1 = Table[
   Table[NIntegrate[(Psi[tcol[[i]]][[j]] - 
        Psi[y][[j]])/(y - tcol[[i]])^(1 + s), {y, tcol[[i]], 1}, 
     Method -> "PrincipalValue", Exclusions -> y - tcol[[i]] == 0, 
     AccuracyGoal -> 6, PrecisionGoal -> 6], {j, nn}], {i, nn}];

 int0 = 
 Table[Table[
   NIntegrate[(Psi[tcol[[i]]][[
       j]])/(tcol[[i]] - y)^(1 + s), {y, -Infinity, 0}, 
    AccuracyGoal -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 8], {j, nn}], {i, nn}];

int2 = Table[
   Table[NIntegrate[(Psi[tcol[[i]]][[j]])/(y - tcol[[i]])^(1 + s), {y,
       1, Infinity}, AccuracyGoal -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 8], {j, 
     nn}], {i, nn}];
 intb0 = 
 Table[NIntegrate[
   uc[y]/(tcol[[i]] - y)^(1 + s), {y, -Infinity, 0}], {i, nn}];

intb1 = Table[
   NIntegrate[uc[y]/(y - tcol[[i]])^(1 + s), {y, 1, Infinity}], {i, 
    nn}];
```

With this definitions we can prepare system of algebraic equations to be solved

```
var = Array[v, {nn}];
u[t_] := var . Psi[t]; lp = d c[1, s] (int + int1 + int0 + int2);
eq = Table[
   var . lp[[i]] - d c[1, s] (intb0[[i]] + intb1[[i]]) + 
     b u[tcol[[i]]] - f[tcol[[i]]] == 0, {i, nn}];
```

This system can be solved with

```
sol = FindRoot[eq, Table[{var[[i]], 1/10}, {i, nn}]]
```

Visualization of numerical solution (red points), exact solution taken from the paper cited (blue line), and absolute error

```
{Show[Plot[{ue[s, t]}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> Blue], 
  ListPlot[Table[{tcol[[i]], Re[u[tcol[[i]]] /. sol]}, {i, nn}], 
   PlotStyle -> Red]], 
 ListPlot[Table[Abs[ue[s, t] - Re[u[t] /. sol]], {t, tcol}], 
  PlotRange -> All, Filling -> Axis]}
```

Note, that maximal error is about $1.88\times 10^{-6}$ for 16 collocation points.
[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much. Which parts of the code should I change if I wanted to change the domain from $(0,1)$ to a generic interval $(a,b)$ with $a,b \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: I also wonder if this could be done also for the parabolic version of the problem, but I'll ask it in a new post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/266475/solve-1d-fractional-parabolic-equations-with-mathematica

Comment: @Riku Normally there is no problem to map $(a, b)$ on $(0, 1$. But may be you have example with points $a, b$ and known solution, then we can consider this case in a new post. Parabolic equation is a good example too :)