# Solve 1d fractional parabolic equations with Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, boundary-conditions

How can we use Mathematica to solve the following fractional parabolic problem?
$$\partial_t u(t,x) +a(-\Delta)^su(t,x) + bu(t,x)= f(t,x) \quad t >0, \ x \in  (\alpha,\beta),\\
u(t,x) = u_c(t,x)\quad t \ge 0, \   x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus  (\alpha,\beta), \\
u(0,x) = u_0(x) \quad x \in  (\alpha,\beta)$$
for $a,b\ge0$ and smooth functions u_c, u_0, f.
Here $(-\Delta)^s$ is the [singular integral fractional Laplacian](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/mediawiki/index.php/Fractional_Laplacian?#As_a_singular_integral).

The stationary case of this problem was brilliantly solved in a related post: [Solve 1d fractional equation with Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/266357/solve-1d-fractional-equation-with-mathematica/266460)

Comment: What about parameters $a, b$ in equation definition?  Is it typo that these parameters used in interval definition as end points, while in initial data there is unit interval?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The numerical algorithm is not so differ from that we described on this [page](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/266357/solve-1d-fractional-equation-with-mathematica/266460?noredirect=1#comment664330_266460). We can use collocation method and Euler wavelets as well as follows

```
c[n_, a_] := a 2^(a - 1) Gamma[(a + n)/2]/(Pi^(n/2) Gamma[1 - a/2]);
lap[n_, a_, x_, u_] := 
  c[n, a] Integrate[(u[x] - u[y])/Abs[x - y]^(n + a), y];

UE[m_, t_] := EulerE[m, t]
psi[k_, n_, m_, t_] := 
 Piecewise[{{2^(k/2) Sqrt[2/Pi] UE[m, 2^k t - 2 n + 1], (n - 1)/
      2^(k - 1) <= t < n/2^(k - 1)}, {0, True}}]
PsiE[k_, M_, t_] := 
 Flatten[Table[psi[k, n, m, t], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]
k0 = 3; M0 = 4; nn = 
 Total[With[{k = k0, M = M0}, 
   Flatten[Table[1, {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]]]; dx = 
 1/(nn); xl = Table[l*dx, {l, 0, nn}]; tcol = 
 Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, nn + 1}]; Psijk = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, PsiE[k, M, t1]]; Psi[y_] := Psijk /. t1 -> y;
s = 1/2; d = 1; b = 1; ue[a_, x_] := (1 + x^2)^(-(1 - a)/2); 
uc[x_, t_] := ue[s, x] Exp[-t];
lape[a_, x_, t_] := 
  Exp[-t] 2^a Gamma[(1 + a)/2]/Gamma[(1 - a)/2] (1 + x^2)^(-(1 + a)/2);


int = 
   Table[Table[
       NIntegrate[(Psi[tcol[[i]]][[j]] - 
               Psi[y][[j]])/(tcol[[i]] - y)^(1 + s), {y, 0, 
      tcol[[i]]}, 
         Method -> "PrincipalValue", Exclusions -> tcol[[i]] - y == 0, 
         AccuracyGoal -> 6, PrecisionGoal -> 6], {j, nn}], {i, nn}];

int1 = Table[
      Table[NIntegrate[(Psi[tcol[[i]]][[j]] - 
                Psi[y][[j]])/(y - tcol[[i]])^(1 + s), {y, tcol[[i]], 
      1}, 
          Method -> "PrincipalValue", 
     Exclusions -> y - tcol[[i]] == 0, 
          AccuracyGoal -> 6, PrecisionGoal -> 6], {j, nn}], {i, nn}];

 int0 = 
   Table[Table[
       NIntegrate[(Psi[tcol[[i]]][[
                j]])/(tcol[[i]] - y)^(1 + s), {y, -Infinity, 0}, 
         AccuracyGoal -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 8], {j, nn}], {i, nn}];

int2 = Table[
      Table[
    NIntegrate[(Psi[tcol[[i]]][[j]])/(y - tcol[[i]])^(1 + s), {y,
             1, Infinity}, AccuracyGoal -> 10, 
     PrecisionGoal -> 8], {j, 
          nn}], {i, nn}];
 intb0 = 
   Table[NIntegrate[
       uc[y, 0]/(tcol[[i]] - y)^(1 + s), {y, -Infinity, 0}], {i, nn}];

intb1 = Table[
      NIntegrate[
    uc[y, 0]/(y - tcol[[i]])^(1 + s), {y, 1, Infinity}], {i, 
        nn}];



var[t_] := Table[v[i][t], {i, nn}]; ic = 
 Table[u[tcol[[i]], 0] == uc[tcol[[i]], 0], {i, nn}];
u[x_, t_] := var[t] . Psi[x]; lp = 
 d c[1, s] (int + int1 + int0 + int2);

f[x_, t_] := lape[s, x, t] + b uc[x, t] - uc[x, t]; eq = 
 Table[D[u[tcol[[i]], t], t] + var[t] . lp[[i]] - 
    d c[1, s] Exp[-t] (intb0[[i]] + intb1[[i]]) + 
    b u[tcol[[i]], t] - (f[tcol[[i]], t]) == 0, {i, nn}];

sol = NDSolve[{eq, ic}, Table[v[i], {i, nn}], {t, 0, 1}];
```

Visualization numerical solution and difference exact and numerical solutions in collocation points. Note that maximal absolute error is about $1.17\times 10^{-6}$ for 16 collocation points.

```
{Plot3D[u[x, t] /. sol[[1]], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Mesh -> None, PlotTheme -> "Marketing", 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic], 
 Plot[Evaluate[Table[uc[x, t] - u[x, t] /. sol, {x, tcol}]], {t, 0, 
   1}, PlotLegends -> tcol, AxesLabel -> Automatic]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

In a case of arbitrary interval $x_0 < x < x_1$ the code can be modified as follows (in this example $x_0=-2, x_1=1$)

```
c[n_, a_] := a 2^(a - 1) Gamma[(a + n)/2]/(Pi^(n/2) Gamma[1 - a/2]);
lap[n_, a_, x_, u_] := 
  c[n, a] Integrate[(u[x] - u[y])/Abs[x - y]^(n + a), y];

UE[m_, t_] := EulerE[m, t]
psi[k_, n_, m_, t_] := 
 Piecewise[{{2^(k/2) Sqrt[2/Pi] UE[m, 2^k t - 2 n + 1], (n - 1)/
      2^(k - 1) <= t < n/2^(k - 1)}, {0, True}}]
PsiE[k_, M_, t_] := 
 Flatten[Table[psi[k, n, m, t], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]
k0 = 3; M0 = 4; x0 = -2; x1 = 1; nn = 
 Total[With[{k = k0, M = M0}, 
   Flatten[Table[1, {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]]]; dx = (x1 - 
    x0)/(nn); xl = Table[x0 + l*dx, {l, 0, nn}]; tcol = 
 Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, nn + 1}]; Psijk = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, PsiE[k, M, t1]]; 
Psi[y_] := Psijk /. t1 -> (y - x0)/(x1 - x0);
s = 1/2; d = 1; b = 1; ue[a_, x_] := (1 + x^2)^(-(1 - a)/2);
uc[x_, t_] := ue[s, x] Exp[-t];
lape[a_, x_, t_] := 
  Exp[-t] 2^a Gamma[(1 + a)/2]/Gamma[(1 - a)/2] (1 + x^2)^(-(1 + a)/2);


int = Table[
   Table[NIntegrate[(Psi[tcol[[i]]][[j]] - 
        Psi[y][[j]])/(tcol[[i]] - y)^(1 + s), {y, x0, tcol[[i]]}, 
     Method -> "PrincipalValue", Exclusions -> tcol[[i]] - y == 0, 
     AccuracyGoal -> 6, PrecisionGoal -> 6], {j, nn}], {i, nn}];

int1 = Table[
   Table[NIntegrate[(Psi[tcol[[i]]][[j]] - 
        Psi[y][[j]])/(y - tcol[[i]])^(1 + s), {y, tcol[[i]], x1}, 
     Method -> "PrincipalValue", Exclusions -> y - tcol[[i]] == 0, 
     AccuracyGoal -> 6, PrecisionGoal -> 6], {j, nn}], {i, nn}];

int0 = Table[
   Table[NIntegrate[(Psi[tcol[[i]]][[j]])/(tcol[[i]] - y)^(1 + 
         s), {y, -Infinity, x0}, AccuracyGoal -> 10, 
     PrecisionGoal -> 8], {j, nn}], {i, nn}];

int2 = Table[
   Table[NIntegrate[(Psi[tcol[[i]]][[j]])/(y - tcol[[i]])^(1 + s), {y,
       x1, Infinity}, AccuracyGoal -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 8], {j, 
     nn}], {i, nn}];
intb0 = Table[
   NIntegrate[
    uc[y, 0]/(tcol[[i]] - y)^(1 + s), {y, -Infinity, x0}], {i, nn}];

intb1 = Table[
   NIntegrate[
    uc[y, 0]/(y - tcol[[i]])^(1 + s), {y, x1, Infinity}], {i, nn}];



var[t_] := Table[v[i][t], {i, nn}]; ic = 
 Table[u[tcol[[i]], 0] == uc[tcol[[i]], 0], {i, nn}];
u[x_, t_] := var[t] . Psi[x]; lp = 
 d c[1, s] (int + int1 + int0 + int2);

f[x_, t_] := lape[s, x, t] + b uc[x, t] - uc[x, t]; eq = 
 Table[D[u[tcol[[i]], t], t] + var[t] . lp[[i]] - 
    d c[1, s] Exp[-t] (intb0[[i]] + intb1[[i]]) + 
    b u[tcol[[i]], t] - (f[tcol[[i]], t]) == 0, {i, nn}];

sol = NDSolve[{eq, ic}, Table[v[i], {i, nn}], {t, 0, 1}];
```

Visualization of numerical solution and error in collocation points
[image: Figure 2]

Note, that in this case the maximal absolute error is about $3.14\times 10^{-4}$, and this is much higher then in the case of unit interval. To decrease error we can increase number of collocation points, for example from 16 to 28 with `k0=3, M0=7`. In this case the maximal absolute error is about $1.18\times 10^{-6}$, that practically is same as in previous example with unit interval.
[image: Figure 3]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is great! Indeed, I had a typo in the question (the interval was supposed to be $(\alpha, \beta)$. What happens if it is e.g. (-1,1)?

Comment: @Riku See update to my answer with numerical solution on an arbitrary interval $x_0 < x < x_1$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Riku You are welcome! See last update with 28 collocation points and maximal error about $1.18\times 10^-6$

Comment: Thanks for the update! That's great news. By the way, I tried to adapt your code to the hyperbolic case, but I couldn't make it work. I've posted the attempt to this post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/266701/solve-hyperbolic-fractional-problem-in-1d If you have some time, could you please take a look?

Comment: Also, I have one more curiosity: I tried to change the parameters, but considering (-\Delta)^s with s>1/2 (that is, s>1 in the notation of your code), produces errors "NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy..." What happened?

Comment: @Riku This is `NIntegrate` numerical challenge since exact solution `ue[a_, x_] := (1 + x^2)^(-(1 - a)/2)` we have used in our code diverges for `a>1`  at   `x->+-Infinity`. Try for instance, `s=0.9` and use `NIntegrate[]// Quiet` in every table `int, int1, int0`. Run the last code with 28 collocation points and check that maximal absolute error of numerical solution is about $3\times 10^{-4}$.   Also note, that in the case `s=1` we have `ue=1`. Try `s=.95` to reproduce this solution.  :)

Comment: Thanks again for all your help! Looking into the reference you mentioned, I had a curiosity about a higher-order and nonlinear version of this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/267030/nonlinear-equation-with-fractional-derivative-in-1d which seems trickier but related