# Nonlinear higher-order equation with fractional derivative in 1d

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics

How can I use Mathematica to solve the following higher order and nonlinear fractional equation?
$$\partial_t u(t,x) +\partial_x(u^k(t,x)\partial_x(-\Delta)^su(t,x)) = f(t,x) \quad t >0, \ x \in  (\alpha,\beta),\\
u(t,x) = u_c \quad t \ge 0, \   x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus  (\alpha,\beta), \\
(-\Delta)^su(t,x) = 0, \quad t \ge 0, \   x \in \{\alpha,\beta\}, \\
u(0,x) = u_0(x) \quad x \in  (\alpha,\beta)$$
for a *real* number $k \ge 1$ and smooth functions u_0,u_c f.
Here $(-\Delta)^s$ is the [singular integral fractional Laplacian](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/mediawiki/index.php/Fractional_Laplacian?#As_a_singular_integral).

Note that the second-order and linear case was amazingly solved in [Solve 1d fractional parabolic equations with Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/266475/solve-1d-fractional-parabolic-equations-with-mathematica)

Also note that a similar example (for only k = 1 and including an additional term) appears in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.00164.pdf

---

Additionally, I would also be interested in the case where $(-\Delta)^s$ is the spectral fractional Laplacian and the boundary conditions are replaced by
$$\partial_x u(t,x) = u_c \quad t \ge 0, \   x \in  \{\alpha,\beta\}, \\
u^k(t,x)\partial_x(-\Delta)^su(t,x) = 0, \quad t \ge 0, \   x \in \{\alpha,\beta\}, \\
$$

Answer (score 5):

We can solve this problem in two steps. First we compute fractional Laplacian $v=(-\Delta)^\frac{s}{2}u$, and then we solve fractional thin film equation
$\partial_tu=\partial_x(u^k\partial_x v)$. Code for the step one is based on the colocation method with using Euler wavelets (see my previous answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/266475/solve-1d-fractional-parabolic-equations-with-mathematica/266489?noredirect=1#comment665628_266489) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/266701/solve-hyperbolic-fractional-problem-in-1d)). Let define exact solution to test code

```
c[n_, a_] := a 2^(a - 1) Gamma[(a + n)/2]/(Pi^(n/2) Gamma[1 - a/2]);
lap[n_, a_, x_, u_] := 
  c[n, a] Integrate[(u[x] - u[y])/Abs[x - y]^(n + a), y];
ue[a_, x_] := (1 + x^2)^(-(1 - a)/2);
uc[x_, t_] := ue[s, x] (c0 kp (1/(c0 kp) - t))^(-1/kp); 
vc[x_, t_] := (c0 kp (1/(c0 kp) - t))^(-1/kp)
   2^s Gamma[(1 + s)/2]/Gamma[(1 - s)/2] (1 + x^2)^(-(1 + s)/2);
lape[a_, x_, t_] := (c0 kp (1/(c0 kp) - t))^(-1/kp)
    2^a Gamma[(1 + a)/2]/Gamma[(1 - a)/2] (1 + x^2)^(-(1 + a)/2);
f[x_, t_] := 
  1/Gamma[(1 - s)/2] (1 - c0 kp t)^(-1 - 1/kp) (1 + x^2)^(-(5/2) - s/
    2) (-c0 (1 + x^2)^(2 + s) Gamma[(1 - s)/2] + 
     2^s kp (-1 + s) (1 + s) (-1 + 
        c0 kp t) x^2 ((1 - c0 kp t)^(-1/kp) (1 + x^2)^(1/2 (-1 + s)))^
      kp Gamma[(1 + s)/2] - 
     2^s (1 + s) (3 + s) (-1 + 
        c0 kp t) x^2 ((1 - c0 kp t)^(-1/kp) (1 + x^2)^(1/2 (-1 + s)))^
      kp Gamma[(1 + s)/2] + 
     2^s (1 + s) (-1 + c0 kp t) (1 + 
        x^2) ((1 - c0 kp t)^(-1/kp) (1 + x^2)^(1/2 (-1 + s)))^
      kp Gamma[(1 + s)/2]);
```

Here `kp=k` and `c0` some parameters defined below. On these lines we define wavelets and function to be solved

```
UE[m_, t_] := EulerE[m, t]
psi[k_, n_, m_, t_] := 
 Piecewise[{{2^(k/2) Sqrt[2/Pi] UE[m, 2^k t - 2 n + 1], (n - 1)/
      2^(k - 1) <= t < n/2^(k - 1)}, {0, True}}]
PsiE[k_, M_, t_] := 
 Flatten[Table[psi[k, n, m, t], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]
k0 = 2; M0 = 3; x0 = 0; x1 = 1; nn = 
 Total[With[{k = k0, M = M0}, 
   Flatten[Table[1, {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]]]; dx = (x1 - 
    x0)/(nn); xl = Table[x0 + l*dx, {l, 0, nn}]; xcol = 
 tcol = Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, nn + 1}]; Psijk = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, PsiE[k, M, t1]]; Intx1 = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, Integrate[PsiE[k, M, t1], t1]];
Intx2 = Integrate[Intx1, t1]; 
intx1[y_] := Intx1 /. t1 -> (y - x0)/(x1 - x0); 
intx2[y_] := Intx2 /. t1 -> (y - x0)/(x1 - x0); 
Psi[y_] := Psijk /. t1 -> (y - x0)/(x1 - x0);

varu[t_] := Table[u[i][t], {i, nn}]; 
varv[t_] := Table[v[i][t], {i, nn}]; 
v[x_, t_] := varv[t] . intx2[x] + x v0[t] + v01[t]; 
v1[x_, t_] := varv[t] . intx1[x] + v0[t]; 
v2[x_, t_] := varv[t] . Psi[x]; 
u[x_, t_] := varu[t] . intx1[x] + u01[t];
u1[x_, t_] := varu[t] . Psi[x];
```

Code to compute fractional Laplacian

```
s = 9/10; kp = 3; c0 = 1/6; int = 
 Table[Table[
    NIntegrate[(intx1[tcol[[i]]][[j]] - 
        intx1[y][[j]])/(tcol[[i]] - y)^(1 + s), {y, x0, tcol[[i]]}, 
     Method -> "PrincipalValue", Exclusions -> tcol[[i]] - y == 0, 
     AccuracyGoal -> 6, PrecisionGoal -> 6], {j, nn}], {i, nn}] // 
  Quiet;

int1 = Table[
    Table[NIntegrate[(intx1[tcol[[i]]][[j]] - 
         intx1[y][[j]])/(y - tcol[[i]])^(1 + s), {y, tcol[[i]], x1}, 
      Method -> "PrincipalValue", Exclusions -> y - tcol[[i]] == 0, 
      AccuracyGoal -> 6, PrecisionGoal -> 6], {j, nn}], {i, nn}] // 
   Quiet;

int0 = Table[
    Table[NIntegrate[(intx1[tcol[[i]]][[
         j]])/(tcol[[i]] - y)^(1 + s), {y, -Infinity, x0}, 
      AccuracyGoal -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 8], {j, nn}], {i, nn}] // 
   Quiet;

int2 = Table[
    Table[NIntegrate[(intx1[tcol[[i]]][[
         j]])/(y - tcol[[i]])^(1 + s), {y, x1, Infinity}, 
      AccuracyGoal -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 8], {j, nn}], {i, nn}] // 
   Quiet;
lp = c[1, s] (int + int1 + int0 + int2) // Re;
```

System of equations, initial and boundary conditions

```
eq = Join[
   Table[D[varu[t], t] . lp[[i]] - D[v[xcol[[i]], t], t] == 0, {i, 
     nn}], Table[-D[u[xcol[[i]], t], t] + 
      u[xcol[[i]], t]^kp v2[xcol[[i]], t] + 
      kp u[xcol[[i]], t]^(kp - 1) u1[xcol[[i]], t] v1[xcol[[i]], t] - 
      f[xcol[[i]], t] == 0, {i, nn}]];
ic = Join[Table[u[tcol[[i]], 0] == uc[tcol[[i]], 0], {i, nn}], 
   Table[v[tcol[[i]], 0] == vc[tcol[[i]], 0], {i, nn}]];
bc = {v[x0, t] == vc[x0, t], v[x1, t] == vc[x1, t], 
  u[x0, t] == uc[x0, t]}; bct = {D[v[x0, t], t] == D[vc[x0, t], t], 
  D[v[x1, t], t] == D[vc[x1, t], t], 
  D[u[x0, t], t] == D[uc[x0, t], t]};
var = Join[{u01, v0, v01}, Table[v[i], {i, nn}], 
  Table[u[i], {i, nn}]]; ic0 = {u[x0, 0] == uc[x0, 0], 
  v[x0, 0] == vc[x0, 0], v[x1, 0] == vc[x1, 0]};
```

Finally we solve system of equations and visualize fractional Laplacian (exact and numeric solution) and error in collocation points

```
sol = NDSolve[{eq, ic, ic0, bct}, var, {t, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}];

{Plot3D[vc[x, t], {x, x0, x1}, {t, 0, 1}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  Mesh -> None, PlotTheme -> "Marketing", AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot3D[v[x, t] /. sol[[1]], {x, x0, x1}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Mesh -> None, PlotTheme -> "Marketing", 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[Evaluate[Table[vc[x, t] - v[x, t] /. sol, {x, tcol}]], {t, 0, 
   1}, PlotLegends -> tcol, AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

It looks nice, but we need to compute $\partial_x v$, and it is why error increases drastically when we using $\partial_x v$ to compute `u`

```
lst = Table[{{x, t}, v1[x, t] /. sol[[1]]}, {x, 
    Join[{x0}, xcol, {x1}]}, {t, 0, 1, .01}];

vx = Interpolation[Flatten[lst, 1], InterpolationOrder -> 4];

U = NDSolveValue[{-D[w[x, t], t] + D[w[x, t]^kp vx[x, t], x] == 
    f[x, t], w[x, 0] == uc[x, 0], w[x0, t] == uc[x0, t], 
   w[x1, t] == uc[x1, t]}, w, {x, x0, x1}, {t, 0, 1}];
```

Visualization exact (left),  numerical solution (center), and error on collocation points

```
{Plot3D[uc[x, t], {x, x0, x1}, {t, 0, 1}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  Mesh -> None, PlotTheme -> "Marketing", AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot3D[U[x, t], {x, x0, x1}, {t, 0, 1}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  Mesh -> None, PlotTheme -> "Marketing", AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[Evaluate[Table[uc[x, t] - U[x, t], {x, tcol}]], {t, 0, 1}, 
  PlotLegends -> tcol, AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: Figure 2]
We also can ignore last step and compute `u` with using `sol`. In this case it looks even better then `U`

```
{Plot3D[uc[x, t], {x, x0, x1}, {t, 0, 1}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  Mesh -> None, PlotTheme -> "Marketing", AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot3D[u[x, t] /. sol[[1]], {x, x0, x1}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Mesh -> None, PlotTheme -> "Marketing", 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[Evaluate[Table[uc[x, t] - u[x, t] /. sol, {x, tcol}]], {t, 0, 
   1}, PlotLegends -> tcol, AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: Figure 3]

Update 1. Note, that in general case the thin film model describes waves. To reproduce wave solutions we can use as initial data `ue` and `ve` from the paper  [Finite difference methods for fractional Laplacians](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.00164v1.pdf) in the form

```
Clear["Global`*"]

ue[x_, k_, s_] := (1 - x^2)^(k + s/2);
lap[x_, k_, s_] := 
  Hypergeometric2F1[(1 + s)/2, -k, 1/2, x^2] 2^s Gamma[
    k + 1 + s/2] Gamma[(1 + s)/2]/(k! Gamma[1/2]);
```

The corresponding `f` can be evaluated as `D[ue[x, k, s]^n D[lap[x, k, s], x], x]`, therefore, we have

```
f[x_, k_, s_, n_] := (1/(Sqrt[\[Pi]] k!))
   2^(2 + s)
     k n (k + s/2) (1 + s) x^2 (1 - x^2)^(-1 + k + s/2) ((1 - x^2)^(
     k + s/2))^(-1 + n)
     Gamma[1 + k + s/2] Gamma[(1 + s)/2] Hypergeometric2F1[1 - k, 
     1 + (1 + s)/2, 3/2, x^2] - (
   2^(1 + s) k (1 + s) ((1 - x^2)^(k + s/2))^
    n Gamma[1 + k + s/2] Gamma[(1 + s)/2] Hypergeometric2F1[1 - k, 
     1 + (1 + s)/2, 3/2, x^2])/(Sqrt[\[Pi]] k!) - (
   2^(3 + s) (1 - k) k (1 + s) (1 + (1 + s)/2) x^2 ((1 - x^2)^(
     k + s/2))^
    n Gamma[1 + k + s/2] Gamma[(1 + s)/2] Hypergeometric2F1[2 - k, 
     2 + (1 + s)/2, 5/2, x^2])/(3 Sqrt[\[Pi]] k!);
```

With this function we solve equation $\partial_tu=\partial_x(u^k\partial_x v)-f$ with using code

```
c[n_, a_] := a 2^(a - 1) Gamma[(a + n)/2]/(Pi^(n/2) Gamma[1 - a/2]);
res = {0 < a < 2};
lapc[n_, a_, x_, u_] := 
  c[n, a] Integrate[(u[x] - u[y])/Abs[x - y]^(n + a), y];

UE[m_, t_] := EulerE[m, t]
psi[k_, n_, m_, t_] := 
 Piecewise[{{2^(k/2) Sqrt[2/Pi] UE[m, 2^k t - 2 n + 1], (n - 1)/
      2^(k - 1) <= t < n/2^(k - 1)}, {0, True}}]
PsiE[k_, M_, t_] := 
 Flatten[Table[psi[k, n, m, t], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]
k0 = 2; M0 = 4; x0 = -1; x1 = 1; nn = 
 Total[With[{k = k0, M = M0}, 
   Flatten[Table[1, {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]]]; dx = (x1 - 
    x0)/(nn); xl = Table[x0 + l*dx, {l, 0, nn}]; xcol = 
 tcol = Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, nn + 1}]; Psijk = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, PsiE[k, M, t1]]; Intx1 = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, Integrate[PsiE[k, M, t1], t1]];
Intx2 = Integrate[Intx1, t1]; 
intx1[y_] := Intx1 /. t1 -> (y - x0)/(x1 - x0); 
intx2[y_] := Intx2 /. t1 -> (y - x0)/(x1 - x0); 
Psi[y_] := Psijk /. t1 -> (y - x0)/(x1 - x0);

varu[t_] := Table[u[i][t], {i, nn}]; 
varv[t_] := Table[v[i][t], {i, nn}]; 
v[x_, t_] := varv[t] . intx2[x] + x v0[t] + v01[t]; 
v1[x_, t_] := varv[t] . intx1[x] + v0[t]; 
v2[x_, t_] := varv[t] . Psi[x]; 
u[x_, t_] := varu[t] . intx1[x] + u01[t];
u1[x_, t_] := varu[t] . Psi[x];

s = 1/8; kp = 2; L = 2 (1 + s) c[1, s]; mL = 
 Gamma[2 + s/2] Gamma[5/2 + s/2]; uc[x_] := 1.5 ue[x, 1, s]; 
vc[x_] := lap[x, 1, s];

int = Table[
    Table[NIntegrate[(intx1[tcol[[i]]][[j]] - 
         intx1[y][[j]])/(tcol[[i]] - y)^(1 + s), {y, x0, tcol[[i]]}, 
      Method -> "PrincipalValue", Exclusions -> tcol[[i]] - y == 0, 
      AccuracyGoal -> 6, PrecisionGoal -> 6], {j, nn}], {i, nn}] // 
   Quiet;

int1 = Table[
    Table[NIntegrate[(intx1[tcol[[i]]][[j]] - 
         intx1[y][[j]])/(y - tcol[[i]])^(1 + s), {y, tcol[[i]], x1}, 
      Method -> "PrincipalValue", Exclusions -> y - tcol[[i]] == 0, 
      AccuracyGoal -> 6, PrecisionGoal -> 6], {j, nn}], {i, nn}] // 
   Quiet;

int0 = Table[
    Table[NIntegrate[(intx1[tcol[[i]]][[
         j]])/(tcol[[i]] - y)^(1 + s), {y, -Infinity, x0}, 
      AccuracyGoal -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 8], {j, nn}], {i, nn}] // 
   Quiet;

int2 = Table[
    Table[NIntegrate[(intx1[tcol[[i]]][[
         j]])/(y - tcol[[i]])^(1 + s), {y, x1, Infinity}, 
      AccuracyGoal -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 8], {j, nn}], {i, nn}] // 
   Quiet;
(*intb0=Table[NIntegrate[uc[y,0]/(tcol[[i]]-y)^(1+s),{y,-Infinity,x0}]\
,{i,nn}]//Quiet;
intb1=Table[NIntegrate[uc[y,0]/(y-tcol[[i]])^(1+s),{y,x1,Infinity}],{\
i,nn}];*)
lp = c[1, s] (int + int1 + int0 + int2) // Re;
(*eq1=v[x,t]==(-\[CapitalDelta])^(s/2)u[x,t];
eq2=-D[u[x,t],t]+u[x,t]^k D[v[x,t],x,x]+k u[x,t]^(k-1) \
D[u[x,t],x]D[v[x,t],x]+L x D[u[x,t],x]+L u[x,t];*)

eq = Join[
   Table[D[varu[t], t] . lp[[i]] - D[v[xcol[[i]], t], t] == 0, {i, 
     nn}], Table[-D[u[xcol[[i]], t], t] + 
      u[xcol[[i]], t]^kp v2[xcol[[i]], t] + 
      kp u[xcol[[i]], t]^(kp - 1) u1[xcol[[i]], t] v1[xcol[[i]], t] - 
      f[xcol[[i]], 1, s, kp] == 0, {i, nn}]];
ic = Join[Table[u[tcol[[i]], 0] == uc[tcol[[i]]], {i, nn}], 
   Table[v[tcol[[i]], 0] == vc[tcol[[i]]], {i, nn}]];
bc = {v[x0, t] == vc[x0, t], v[x1, t] == vc[x1, t], 
  u[x0, t] == uc[x0, t]}; bct = {D[v[x0, t], t] == 0, 
  D[v[x1, t], t] == 0, D[u[x0, t], t] == 0};
var = Join[{u01, v0, v01}, Table[v[i], {i, nn}], 
  Table[u[i], {i, nn}]]; ic0 = {u[x0, 0] == 0, v[x0, 0] == vc[x0], 
  v[x1, 0] == vc[x1]};

sol = NDSolve[{eq, ic, ic0, bct}, var, {t, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}];
```

Visualization numerical solution with very clear waves for `u` (left) and `v` (right)

```
{Plot3D[u[x, t] /. sol[[1]], {x, x0, x1}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Mesh -> None, PlotTheme -> "Marketing", 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50], 
 Plot3D[v[x, t] /. sol[[1]], {x, x0, x1}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Mesh -> None, PlotTheme -> "Marketing", 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50]}
```

[image: Figure 4]

Update 2. We can exclude step with fractional Laplacian computation and compute numerical solution in the first case as follows

```
c[n_, a_] := a 2^(a - 1) Gamma[(a + n)/2]/(Pi^(n/2) Gamma[1 - a/2]);
lap[n_, a_, x_, u_] := 
  c[n, a] Integrate[(u[x] - u[y])/Abs[x - y]^(n + a), y];
ue[a_, x_] := (1 + x^2)^(-(1 - a)/2);
uc[x_, t_] := ue[s, x] (c0 kp (1/(c0 kp) - t))^(-1/kp); 
vc[x_, t_] := (c0 kp (1/(c0 kp) - t))^(-1/kp)
   2^s Gamma[(1 + s)/2]/Gamma[(1 - s)/2] (1 + x^2)^(-(1 + s)/2);
lape[a_, x_, t_] := (c0 kp (1/(c0 kp) - t))^(-1/kp)
    2^a Gamma[(1 + a)/2]/Gamma[(1 - a)/2] (1 + x^2)^(-(1 + a)/2);
f[x_, t_] := 
  1/Gamma[(1 - s)/2] (1 - c0 kp t)^(-1 - 1/kp) (1 + x^2)^(-(5/2) - s/
    2) (-c0 (1 + x^2)^(2 + s) Gamma[(1 - s)/2] + 
     2^s kp (-1 + s) (1 + s) (-1 + 
        c0 kp t) x^2 ((1 - c0 kp t)^(-1/kp) (1 + x^2)^(1/2 (-1 + s)))^
      kp Gamma[(1 + s)/2] - 
     2^s (1 + s) (3 + s) (-1 + 
        c0 kp t) x^2 ((1 - c0 kp t)^(-1/kp) (1 + x^2)^(1/2 (-1 + s)))^
      kp Gamma[(1 + s)/2] + 
     2^s (1 + s) (-1 + c0 kp t) (1 + 
        x^2) ((1 - c0 kp t)^(-1/kp) (1 + x^2)^(1/2 (-1 + s)))^
      kp Gamma[(1 + s)/2]);
UE[m_, t_] := EulerE[m, t]
psi[k_, n_, m_, t_] := 
 Piecewise[{{2^(k/2) Sqrt[2/Pi] UE[m, 2^k t - 2 n + 1], (n - 1)/
      2^(k - 1) <= t < n/2^(k - 1)}, {0, True}}]
PsiE[k_, M_, t_] := 
 Flatten[Table[psi[k, n, m, t], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]
k0 = 2; M0 = 4; x0 = 0; x1 = 1; nn = 
 Total[With[{k = k0, M = M0}, 
   Flatten[Table[1, {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]]]; dx = (x1 - 
    x0)/(nn); xl = Table[x0 + l*dx, {l, 0, nn}]; xcol = 
 tcol = Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, nn + 1}]; Psijk = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, PsiE[k, M, t1]]; Intx1 = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, Integrate[PsiE[k, M, t1], t1]];
Intx2 = Integrate[Intx1, t1]; 
intx1[y_] := Intx1 /. t1 -> (y - x0)/(x1 - x0); 
intx2[y_] := Intx2 /. t1 -> (y - x0)/(x1 - x0); 
Psi[y_] := Psijk /. t1 -> (y - x0)/(x1 - x0);

varu[t_] := Table[u[i][t], {i, nn}];
u[x_, t_] := varu[t] . intx2[x] + u01[t] + u0[t] x;
u1[x_, t_] := varu[t] . intx1[x] + u0[t];
u2[x_, t_] := varu[t] . Psi[x];


s = 9/10; kp = 3; c0 = 1/6;
intu1 = Table[
    Table[NIntegrate[(intx1[tcol[[i]]][[j]] - 
         intx1[y][[j]])/(tcol[[i]] - y)^(1 + s), {y, x0, tcol[[i]]}, 
      Method -> "PrincipalValue", Exclusions -> tcol[[i]] - y == 0, 
      AccuracyGoal -> 6, PrecisionGoal -> 6], {j, nn}], {i, nn}] // 
   Quiet;

int1u1 = Table[
    Table[NIntegrate[(intx1[tcol[[i]]][[j]] - 
         intx1[y][[j]])/(y - tcol[[i]])^(1 + s), {y, tcol[[i]], x1}, 
      Method -> "PrincipalValue", Exclusions -> y - tcol[[i]] == 0, 
      AccuracyGoal -> 6, PrecisionGoal -> 6], {j, nn}], {i, nn}] // 
   Quiet;

int0u1 = Table[
    Table[NIntegrate[(intx1[tcol[[i]]][[
         j]])/(tcol[[i]] - y)^(1 + s), {y, -Infinity, x0}, 
      AccuracyGoal -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 8], {j, nn}], {i, nn}] // 
   Quiet;

int2u1 = Table[
    Table[NIntegrate[(intx1[tcol[[i]]][[
         j]])/(y - tcol[[i]])^(1 + s), {y, x1, Infinity}, 
      AccuracyGoal -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 8], {j, nn}], {i, nn}] // 
   Quiet;
intu2 = Table[
    Table[NIntegrate[(Psi[tcol[[i]]][[j]] - 
         Psi[y][[j]])/(tcol[[i]] - y)^(1 + s), {y, x0, tcol[[i]]}, 
      Method -> "PrincipalValue", Exclusions -> tcol[[i]] - y == 0, 
      AccuracyGoal -> 6, PrecisionGoal -> 6], {j, nn}], {i, nn}] // 
   Quiet;

int1u2 = Table[
    Table[NIntegrate[(Psi[tcol[[i]]][[j]] - 
         Psi[y][[j]])/(y - tcol[[i]])^(1 + s), {y, tcol[[i]], x1}, 
      Method -> "PrincipalValue", Exclusions -> y - tcol[[i]] == 0, 
      AccuracyGoal -> 6, PrecisionGoal -> 6], {j, nn}], {i, nn}] // 
   Quiet;

int0u2 = Table[
    Table[NIntegrate[(Psi[tcol[[i]]][[
         j]])/(tcol[[i]] - y)^(1 + s), {y, -Infinity, x0}, 
      AccuracyGoal -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 8], {j, nn}], {i, nn}] // 
   Quiet;

int2u2 = Table[
    Table[NIntegrate[(Psi[tcol[[i]]][[
         j]])/(y - tcol[[i]])^(1 + s), {y, x1, Infinity}, 
      AccuracyGoal -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 8], {j, nn}], {i, nn}] // 
   Quiet;

lpu1 = c[1, s] (intu1 + int1u1 + int0u1 + int2u1) // Re;(*v1*)
lpu2 = c[1, s] (intu2 + int1u2 + int0u2 + int2u2) // Re;(*v2*)


eq = Table[-D[u[xcol[[i]], t], t] + 
     u[xcol[[i]], t]^kp varu[t] . lpu2[[i]] + 
     kp u[xcol[[i]], t]^(kp - 1) u1[xcol[[i]], t] varu[t] . 
       lpu1[[i]] - f[xcol[[i]], t] == 0, {i, nn}];
ic = Table[u[tcol[[i]], 0] == uc[tcol[[i]], 0], {i, nn}];
bc = {u[x0, t] == uc[x0, t], 
  u[x1, t] == uc[x1, t]}; bct = {D[u[x1, t], t] == D[uc[x1, t], t], 
  D[u[x0, t], t] == D[uc[x0, t], t]};
var = Join[{u01, u0}, 
  Table[u[i], {i, nn}]]; ic0 = {u[x0, 0] == uc[x0, 0], 
  u[x1, 0] == uc[x1, 0]};

sol = NDSolve[{eq, ic, ic0, bct}, var, {t, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}];
```

Visualization exact and numerical solution, and error in the collocation points

```
{Plot3D[uc[x, t], {x, x0, x1}, {t, 0, 1}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  Mesh -> None, PlotTheme -> "Marketing", AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot3D[u[x, t] /. sol[[1]], {x, x0, x1}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Mesh -> None, PlotTheme -> "Marketing", 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[Evaluate[Table[uc[x, t] - u[x, t] /. sol, {x, tcol}]], {t, 0, 
   1}, PlotLegends -> tcol, AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: Figure 5]

Comment: Thank you so much! How did you choose vc in this? That is, how is it related to the originally given uc?

Comment: @Riku Fractional Laplacian for `ue[a_, x_] := (1 + x^2)^(-(1 - a)/2)` has been computed in the paper Numerical Methods for the Fractional Laplacian: A Finite Difference-Quadrature Approach by Yanghong Huang and Adam Oberman. I used  this `ue` to construct the time dependent separable solution  `uc[x, t]` and corresponding `vc[x,t]` for fractional thin film equation.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to use (1 + x^2)^(-(1 - a)/2) as initial data of the equation and 2^s Gamma[(1 + s)/2]/Gamma[(1 - s)/2] (1 + x^2)^(-(1 + s)/2) as corresponding initial data for (-\Delta)^s u with external boundary data = 0 and f = 0, but I get as a result that the solution does not move; I'm probably making a mistake, but I don't see where. Could you maybe separate in the data of your question initial conditions from boundary conditions?

Comment: @Riku In the section  System of equations, initial and boundary conditions there are `eq` (equations), `ic` (initial conditions), `bc` (boundary conditions), `bct` (differentiated boundary conditions), `ic0` (initial conditions for `bct`). For usage fractional Laplacian of `ue` see my answer on   https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/266357/solve-1d-fractional-equation-with-mathematica/266460?noredirect=1#comment664330_266460

Comment: I see. It's very strange though: I tried to initialize the same initial condition ue but with zero boundary data and (mistakenly) got a stationary profile for all times 0 < t < 1. For completeness, could you please add a simulation where the initial data is just ue[a_, x_] := (1 + x^2)^(-(1 - a)/2)  (and the corresponding ve[x_]:=2^s Gamma[(1 + s)/2]/Gamma[(1 - s)/2] (1 + x^2)^(-(1 + s)/2) and zero boundary condition?

Comment: @Riku We can't simulate `u` with initial data `u[x,0] == (1 + x^2)^(-(1 - a)/2)` and zero boundary conditions.  For completeness, please, see Update 1 with initial data   `u[x,0]==(1 - x^2)^(k + s/2)` and zero boundary conditions.

Comment: Thank you! What is the role of f in this? I've tried to use the same code but with f=0 and got a time-independent solution (which shouldn't be the case)

Comment: @Riku We need `f` to get some wave solution at  `t>0`.  With `f=0` in the last code we also have some solution but without waves.  How do you compute time-independent solution?

Comment: This is extremely weird though: with initial data ue[x_, k_, s_] := (1 - x^2)^(k + s/2), zero external boundary data and zero source f, theoretically there exists a time-dependent solution u(t,x) to the problem above

Comment: @Riku Solution may be exit, but unfortunately collocation method is very limited since we can't invert matrix at  high `nn`.  So, I am looking for some numerical method different from above.