# Riesz fractional derivatives/Laplacian for Lévy flights?

Tags: differential-equations, random-process, fractional-calculus

There are pretty popular [Lévy flights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_flight) for diffusion with steps of infinite variance, mathematically requiring [Riesz fractional derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus#Riesz_derivative), which in Fourier transform multiplies by $|k|^\alpha$.

I wanted to solve such PDEs, eigensystems for [fractional Schrödinger equations](https://scholar.google.pl/scholar?q=fractional%20schrodinger) like [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/3124320) - replacing Laplacians with fractional; however, in [fractional calculus](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FractionalCalculus.html), there are available only Caputo and Riemann–Liouville fractional derivatives, which seem essentially different than Riesz (?) I have tried going to Fourier or using basis, but there are numerical issues.

Is there a way to use Riesz in `NDSolve[]`, `NDEigenstem[]`, e.g. replace it with something close using Caputo or Riemann–Liouville?

Comment: Please, see my answer on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/273824/plot-eigenvalues-of-fractional-laplacian-in-1d